# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-service, segmentation-fault

I've been reading the other posts on tracking down the reasons for getting a `SIGSEGV` in an Android app. I plan to scour my app for possible NullPointers related to Canvas use, but my `SIGSEGV` barfs up a different memory address each time. Plus I've seen `code=1` and `code=2`. If the memory address was `0x00000000`, I'd have a clue it is a NullPointer.

The last one I got was a `code=2`:

```
A/libc(4969): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x42a637d9 (code=2)
```

Any suggestions on how to track this down?

I have a suspect, but I'm not keen on experimenting with it yet. My app uses the OSMDroid API for offline mapping. The OverlayItem class represents markers/nodes on the map. I have a Service that collects data via the network to populate the OverlayItem which are then displayed on the map. In an effort to simplify my design, I extended OverlayItem into my own NodeOverlayItem class, which includes some addition attributes I use in the UI Activity and in the Service. This gave me a single point of Item information for the UI and Service. I used Intents to broadcast to the Activity to refresh the UI map when something changed. The Activity binds to the Service and there's a Service method to get the list of NodeOverlayItem's. I think it might be the OSMDroid API's use of OverlayItem, and my Service updating node information at the same time. (a concurrency issue)

As I write this I think that's really the problem. The headache isn't splitting out the Node and OverlayItem from NodeOverlayItem, it's that the Activity will need some data from the Node, that the Service holds. Plus when the Activity is created (onResume, etc...) the OverlayItem objects will need to be re-created from the Node data that the Service has been maintaining while the Activity was away. e.g. You start the app, the Service collects data, the UI displays it, you go to Home, then back to the app, the Activity will need to pull and re-create the OverlayItem's from the latest Service node data.

I know this isn't a great or clear questions. It's like all my SO questions are niche or obscure. If anyone has a suggestion on how to interpret those `SIGSEGV` errors, it would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**
Here's the latest crash captured during a debug session. I have 3 of these devices being used for testing and they don't all crash reliably when I'm developing and testing. I included a bit extra just so the GC logging could be noted. You can see the problem is probably not related to memory exhaustion.

```
03-03 02:02:38.328: I/CommService(7477): Received packet from: 192.168.1.102
03-03 02:02:38.328: I/CommService(7477): Already processed this packet. It's a re-broadcast from another node, or from myself. It's not a repeat broadcast though.
03-03 02:02:38.406: D/CommService(7477): Checking OLSRd info...
03-03 02:02:38.460: D/CommService(7477): Monitoring nodes...
03-03 02:02:38.515: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2050K, 16% free 17151K/20359K, paused 3ms+6ms
03-03 02:02:38.515: I/CommService(7477): Received packet from: 192.168.1.102
03-03 02:02:38.515: D/CommService(7477): Forwarding packet (4f68802cf10684a83ac4936ebb3c934d) along to other nodes.
03-03 02:02:38.609: I/CommService(7477): Received packet from: 192.168.1.100
03-03 02:02:38.609: D/CommService(7477): Forwarding packet (e4bc81e91ec92d06f83e03068f52ab4) along to other nodes.
03-03 02:02:38.609: D/CommService(7477): Already processed this packet: 4204a5b27745ffe5e4f8458e227044bf
03-03 02:02:38.609: A/libc(7477): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x68f52abc (code=1)
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008): Build fingerprint: 'Lenovo/IdeaTab_A1107/A1107:4.0.4/MR1/eng.user.20120719.150703:user/release-keys'
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008): pid: 7477, tid: 7712  >>> com.test.testm <<<
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 68f52abc
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  r0 68f52ab4  r1 412ef268  r2 4d9c3bf4  r3 412ef268
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  r4 001ad8f8  r5 4d9c3bf4  r6 412ef268  r7 4c479df8
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  r8 4d9c3c0c  r9 4c479dec  10 46cf260a  fp 4d9c3c24
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  ip 40262a04  sp 4d9c3bc8  lr 402d01dd  pc 402d0182  cpsr 00000030
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d0  00000001000c0102  d1  3a22364574614c7d
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d2  403fc0000000007d  d3  363737343433350a
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d4  49544341223a2273  d5  6f6567222c224556
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d6  3a223645676e6f4c  d7  000000013835372d
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d8  0000000000000000  d9  4040000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d10 0000000000000000  d11 4040000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d12 4040000000000000  d13 0000000000000021
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d16 3fe62e42fefa39ef  d17 3ff0000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d18 3fe62e42fee00000  d19 0000000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d20 0000000000000000  d21 3ff0000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d22 4028000000000000  d23 3ff0000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d24 0000000000000000  d25 3ff0000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d26 0000000000000000  d27 c028000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d28 0000000000000000  d29 3ff0000000000000
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3fecccccb5c28f6e
03-03 02:02:38.914: I/DEBUG(4008):  scr 60000013
03-03 02:02:39.046: I/DEBUG(4008):          #00  pc 0006b182  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (EVP_DigestFinal_ex)
03-03 02:02:39.046: I/DEBUG(4008):          #01  pc 0006b1d8  /system/lib/libcrypto.so (EVP_DigestFinal)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):          #02  pc 0001f814  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):          #03  pc 0001ec30  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):          #04  pc 00058c70  /system/lib/libdvm.so (_Z16dvmCallJNIMethodPKjP6JValuePK6MethodP6Thread)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): code around pc:
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d0160 0003151e 4604b570 f7ff460d 4620ff81  ....p..F.F.... F
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d0170 f7ff4629 bd70ff93 4604b570 460e6800  )F....p.p..F.h.F
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d0180 68834615 dd062b40 21fa4810 44784a10  .F.h@+...H.!.JxD
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d0190 f7c8447a 6821f80f 698a4620 47904631  zD....!h F.i1F.G
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01a0 b1154606 68836820 6822602b b12b6a13  .F.. h.h+`"h.j+.
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): code around lr:
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01bc 68e06821 21006c4a ea0af7c4 bd704630  !h.hJl.!....0Fp.
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01cc 00031492 000314b5 4604b570 ffcef7ff  ........p..F....
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01dc 46204605 ff12f7ff bd704628 4604b573  .F F....(Fp.s..F
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01ec 2102460d fb36f002 42ab6823 b123d020  .F.!..6.#h.B .#.
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 402d01fc b1136c5b f7c868e0 68a0fccf 05c26025  [l...h.....h%`..
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): memory map around addr 68f52abc:
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): 4d8c5000-4d9c4000 
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): (no map for address)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): b0001000-b0009000 /system/bin/linker
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): stack:
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b88  408d1f90  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b8c  412ef258  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b90  00000001  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b94  408d6c58  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b98  408d6fa8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3b9c  4c479dec  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3ba0  46cf260a  /system/framework/core.odex
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3ba4  408735e7  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3ba8  412ef258  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bac  002bf070  [heap]
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bb0  412ef258  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bb4  00000000  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bb8  412ef268  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bbc  00000000  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bc0  df0027ad  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bc4  00000000  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): #00 4d9c3bc8  001ad8f8  [heap]
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bcc  002ae0b8  [heap]
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bd0  00000004  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bd4  402d01dd  /system/lib/libcrypto.so
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008): #01 4d9c3bd8  001ad8f8  [heap]
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3bdc  002ae0b8  [heap]
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3be0  00000004  
03-03 02:02:39.054: I/DEBUG(4008):     4d9c3be4  4024e817  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
03-03 02:02:39.406: D/CommService(7477): Checking OLSRd info...
03-03 02:02:39.500: D/CommService(7477): Monitoring nodes...
03-03 02:02:39.500: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2073K, 16% free 17118K/20359K, paused 51ms
03-03 02:02:39.632: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1998K, 16% free 17162K/20359K, paused 2ms+4ms
03-03 02:02:40.406: D/CommService(7477): Checking OLSRd info...
03-03 02:02:40.445: D/CommService(7477): Monitoring nodes...
03-03 02:02:40.562: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2045K, 16% free 17158K/20359K, paused 3ms+4ms
03-03 02:02:41.406: D/CommService(7477): Checking OLSRd info...
03-03 02:02:41.445: D/CommService(7477): Monitoring nodes...
03-03 02:02:41.531: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2045K, 16% free 17154K/20359K, paused 3ms+12ms
03-03 02:02:42.406: D/CommService(7477): Checking OLSRd info...
03-03 02:02:42.445: D/CommService(7477): Monitoring nodes...
03-03 02:02:42.507: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2068K, 16% free 17128K/20359K, paused 3ms+4ms
03-03 02:02:42.679: D/dalvikvm(7477): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2006K, 16% free 17161K/20359K, paused 2ms+12ms
03-03 02:02:43.140: I/BootReceiver(1236): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_05 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
03-03 02:02:43.210: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 912K, 17% free 10207K/12295K, paused 62ms
03-03 02:02:43.265: D/dalvikvm(1236): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 243K, 16% free 10374K/12295K, paused 49ms
03-03 02:02:43.265: I/dalvikvm-heap(1236): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.507MB for 196628-byte allocation
```

Comment: Add more information from log about crash.

Comment: I've fixed a bug like this before and would expect to see this happen after the garbage collector is ran. Is that what you are seeing?

Comment: How did you go from one line to that giant stack trace? I'm stuck with the single line and can't figure out why my app is crashing.

Comment: ended up extending all my objects with `Java.Lang.Object` . Sorted out my crashings

Comment: For getting the whole stack trace with address references, simply stop filtering the logcat by your app process. It will be just below the SIGSEGV error.

Comment: For me this was fixed ny moving animation code to be invoked on UI thread

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I found the problem. I don't think this will help a lot of others trying to track down their personal SIGSEGV, but mine (and it was very hard) was entirely related to this:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=8709

The libcrypto.so in my dump kind of clued me in. I do a MD5 hash of packet data when trying to determine if I've already seen the packet, and skipping it if I had. I thought at one point this was an ugly threading issue related to tracking those hashes, but it turned out it was the java.security.MessageDigest class! It's not thread safe!

I swapped it out with a UID I was stuffing in every packet based on the device UUID and a timestamp. No problems since.

I guess the lesson I can impart to those that were in my situation is, even if you're a 100% Java application, pay attention to the native library and symbol noted in the crash dump for clues. Googling for SIGSEGV + the lib .so name will go a lot farther than the useless code=1, etc... Next think about where your Java app could touch native code, even if it's nothing you're doing. I made the mistake of assuming it was a Service + UI threading issue where the Canvas was drawing something that was null, (the most common case I Googled on SIGSEGV) and ignored the possibility it could have been completely related to code I wrote that was related to the lib .so in the crash dump. Naturally java.security would use a native component in libcrypto.so for speed, so once I clued in, I Googled for Android + SIGSEGV + libcrypto.so and found the documented issue.

Comment: Got a similar issue, still with MessageDigest, ok, not thread safe at all. Instead of a nice exception, we get a ugly crash!

Comment: I had similar thing with RSA decryption using Openssl. Moving the operation in a new thread solved the issue.

Answer (score 195):

First, get your tombstone stack trace, it will be printed every time your app crashes. Something like this:

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'XXXXXXXXX'
pid: 1658, tid: 13086  >>> system_server <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 64696f7e
 r0 00000000  r1 00000001  r2 ad12d1e8  r3 7373654d
 r4 64696f72  r5 00000406  r6 00974130  r7 40d14008
 r8 4b857b88  r9 4685adb4  10 00974130  fp 4b857ed8
 ip 00000000  sp 4b857b50  lr afd11108  pc ad115ebc  cpsr 20000030
 d0  4040000040000000  d1  0000004200000003
 d2  4e72cd924285e370  d3  00e81fe04b1b64d8
 d4  3fbc71c7009b64d8  d5  3fe999999999999a
 d6  4010000000000000  d7  4000000000000000
 d8  4000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
 d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
 d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
 d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
 scr 80000012

         #00  pc 000108d8  /system/lib/libc.so
         #01  pc 0003724c  /system/lib/libxvi020.so
         #02  pc 0000ce02  /system/lib/libxvi020.so
         #03  pc 0000d672  /system/lib/libxvi020.so
         #04  pc 00010cce  /system/lib/libxvi020.so
         #05  pc 00004432  /system/lib/libwimax_jni.so
         #06  pc 00011e74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #07  pc 0004354a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #08  pc 00017088  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #09  pc 0001c210  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #10  pc 0001b0f8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #11  pc 00059c24  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #12  pc 00059e3c  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #13  pc 0004e19e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
         #14  pc 00011b94  /system/lib/libc.so
         #15  pc 0001173c  /system/lib/libc.so

code around pc:
ad115e9c 4620eddc bf00bd70 0001736e 0001734e 
ad115eac 4605b570 447c4c0a f7f44620 e006edc8 
ad115ebc 42ab68e3 68a0d103 f7f42122 6864edd2 
ad115ecc d1f52c00 44784803 edbef7f4 bf00bd70 
ad115edc 00017332 00017312 2100b51f 46682210 

code around lr:
afd110e8 e2166903 1a000018 e5945000 e1a02004 
afd110f8 e2055a02 e1a00005 e3851001 ebffed92 
afd11108 e3500000 13856002 1a000001 ea000009 
afd11118 ebfffe50 e1a01004 e1a00006 ebffed92 
afd11128 e1a01005 e1550000 e1a02006 e3a03000 

stack:
    4b857b10  40e43be8  
    4b857b14  00857280  
    4b857b18  00000000  
    4b857b1c  034e8968  
    4b857b20  ad118ce9  /system/lib/libnativehelper.so
    4b857b24  00000002  
    4b857b28  00000406
```

Then, use the `addr2line` utility (find it in your NDK tool-chain) to find the function that crashes. In this sample, you do

```
addr2line -e -f libc.so 0001173c
```

And you will see where you got the problem. Of course this wont help you since it is in libc.

So you might combine the utilities of `arm-eabi-objdump` to find the final target.

Believe me, it is a tough task.

---

---

---

Just for an update. I think I was doing Android native build from the whole-source-tree for quite a long time, until today I have myself carefully read the NDK documents. Ever since the release NDK-r6, it has provided a utility called `ndk-stack`.

Following is the content from official NDK documents with the NDK-r9 tar ball.

**Overview:**

`ndk-stack` is a simple tool that allows you to filter stack traces as they appear in the output of 'adb logcat' and replace any address inside a shared library with the corresponding : values.

In a nutshell, it will translate something like:

```
  I/DEBUG   (   31): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
  I/DEBUG   (   31): Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
  I/DEBUG   (   31): pid: 351, tid: 351  %gt;%gt;%gt; /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher <<<
  I/DEBUG   (   31): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0d9f00d8
  I/DEBUG   (   31):  r0 0000af88  r1 0000a008  r2 baadf00d  r3 0d9f00d8
  I/DEBUG   (   31):  r4 00000004  r5 0000a008  r6 0000af88  r7 00013c44
  I/DEBUG   (   31):  r8 00000000  r9 00000000  10 00000000  fp 00000000
  I/DEBUG   (   31):  ip 0000959c  sp be956cc8  lr 00008403  pc 0000841e  cpsr 60000030
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #00  pc 0000841e  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #01  pc 000083fe  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #02  pc 000083f6  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #03  pc 000191ac  /system/lib/libc.so
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #04  pc 000083ea  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #05  pc 00008458  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher
  I/DEBUG   (   31):          #06  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
  I/DEBUG   (   31):
```

Into the more readable output:

```
  ********** Crash dump: **********
  Build fingerprint: 'generic/google_sdk/generic/:2.2/FRF91/43546:eng/test-keys'
  pid: 351, tid: 351  >>> /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher <<<
  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), fault addr 0d9f00d8
  Stack frame #00  pc 0000841e  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher : Routine zoo in /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/zoo.c:13
  Stack frame #01  pc 000083fe  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher : Routine bar in /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/bar.c:5
  Stack frame #02  pc 000083f6  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher : Routine my_comparison in /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/foo.c:9
  Stack frame #03  pc 000191ac  /system/lib/libc.so
  Stack frame #04  pc 000083ea  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher : Routine foo in /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/foo.c:14
  Stack frame #05  pc 00008458  /data/local/ndk-tests/crasher : Routine main in /tmp/foo/crasher/jni/main.c:19
  Stack frame #06  pc 0000d362  /system/lib/libc.so
```

**Usage:**

To do this, you will first need a directory containing symbolic versions of your application's shared libraries. If you use the NDK build system (i.e. `ndk-build`), then these are always located under $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/, where  stands for your device's ABI (i.e. `armeabi` by default).

You can feed the `logcat` text either as direct input to the program, e.g.:

```
adb logcat | $NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi
```

Or you can use the -dump option to specify the logcat as an input file, e.g.:

```
adb logcat > /tmp/foo.txt
$NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi -dump foo.txt
```

IMPORTANT :

The tool looks for the initial line containing starts in the `logcat` output, i.e. something that looks like:

```
 *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
```

When copy/pasting traces, don't forget this line from the traces, or `ndk-stack` won't work correctly.

TODO:

A future version of `ndk-stack` will try to launch `adb logcat` and select the library path automatically. For now, you'll have to do these steps manually.

As of now, `ndk-stack` doesn't handle libraries that don't have debug information in them. It may be useful to try to detect the nearest function entry point to a given PC address (e.g. as in the libc.so example above).

Comment: Sorry Robin. I appreciate the answer. If I had posted my crash dump, which I did in another Question about it specifically, you might have been able to answer in context. However I decided to give you the 100 bounty (of my precious rep!) as you were the only one anywhere that tried to address the task of tracing the crash back to the native library source.

Comment: Hi Robin. thanks a lot for a detailed and informative answer. I was wondering that, is it possible to print the information inside the native libraries. My native libraries have a lot of debugging information which i printed using `printf`. Can i see the output of that `printf` from the native libraries.

Comment: #include <android/Log.h> #define LOGD(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG,"YOURTAG",__VA_ARGS__)

Comment: you just saved me days of debugging with that ndk-stack command! I really don't understand how come I didn't find it before...

Comment: okay I have printed the crash dump but still do not understand the output.

Comment: Sorry, where is the `obj/local/armeabi`? I cannot find it :(

Comment: If you are on Android Studio, make sure the logcat filter is set to "No Filters", otherwise the details will be filtered out and not displayed.

Answer (score 53):

I was getting this error by saving an object to the shared preferences as a gson converted string. The gson String was no good, so retrieving and deserializing the object was not actually working correctly. This meant any subsequent accesses to the object resulted in this error. Scary :)

Comment: Thanks, this just saved my life :)))
You will get this if the object that gson tries to convert doesn't have an valid constructor (I was trying it with android.Location class, giving this error)

Comment: @rosualin Oh my god! This may be exactly my problem (pulling out my hair over here). I am too storing the `android.Location` object in `SharedPreferences` in a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. Most of the times it works but sometimes I get the dreaded `SIGSEGV` crash. Can you please share how you solved it?

Comment: @rosualin I moved the operational stuff out of the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to an `IntentService` that I invoke from the receiver via `startWakefulService()` method, but still the same outcome. Please share if you have anything.

Comment: Well I was trying to save android.Location or Geofence in shared preferences, and not having a constructor, it would cause that. So I did a custom class, with the data I needed and just saved that. Hope it helps.

Comment: @rosualin Thanks for the reply. Actually I was too thinking of doing something similar, as I need only the lat & long from the `android.Location` object, I was thinking of storing them as `Strings` in `SharedPreferences`. But yeah, I'll try your approach. P.S. I am too, storing the locations for Geofencing. Google's limit to register only 100 locations is screwing us over!

Comment: @rosualin It worked!!!!!!!!!!! You are a life saver!!! I was going crazy on this stupid bug for the past 4 days. Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 36):

I also got this error many times and I solved it.
This error will be faced in case of memory management in native side.

Your application is accessing memory outside of its address space. This is most likely an invalid pointer access. SIGSEGV = segmentation fault in native code. Since it is not occurring in Java code you won't see a stack trace with details. However, you may still see some stack trace information in the logcat if you look around a bit after the application process crashes. It will not tell you the line number within the file, but will tell you which object files and addresses were in use in the call chain. From there you can often figure out which area of the code is problematic. You can also setup a gdb native connection to the target process and catch it in the debugger.

Comment: In my case it was that the underlying component of java.security.MessageDigest was not thread safe and I was accessing it from 2 threads. (create the hash and store, then create the hash and compare)

Comment: Your not getting this fatal-exception due to java.security,MessageDigest or any thread.

It may not be the exact location where memory is being corrupted. E.g. if you corrupt the heap, any number of operations later may be effected, and it could well be outside of NDK space.
You won't know until the end of the function .

Comment: Just suppose if your code breaks in line 10 in native side,then even after this, your code will be running fine & after executing some lines of code,it will throw this error in java part.

It happens. "Java will throw exceptions when you move outside of the memory". Yes, luckily, but just to clarify , if he oversteps memory in C/C++ and it moves on to Java, the app can crash without throwing a standard Java exception.

Thats why fatal ecxeption will occur.

Comment: Try to find out error in native side, where you used any data-array.
In most cases,this will occur in data-arrays, when by-mistake you cross its bounds or data-limit.

Answer (score 33):

For me, on Android Studio 4.1, what did the trick was good ole **File** > **Invalidate Cache & Restart**

No more Fatal Signals after that. I'm sure it had something to do with the profiler, but can't be certain. I just know restarting AS stopped the crashes on my emulator.
[image]

Comment: yes.. this happens with Android Studio 4.1 and debugging, so annoying

Comment: I kept getting this while profiling my app in AS 4.1.3

Comment: Fixed it for me als well (version: 2020.3.1 Patch 2)

Comment: just had it in 2021.3.1 Patch 1

Answer (score 28):

Today I faced `Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x8 in tid 18161` issue and I struggle half day to solve this.

I tried many things clearing cache and deleting .gradle file and all.

Finally I `disable Instant Run` and now I am not getting this issue again.
Now my application is working after enabling instant run also. It may be the instant run problem, Try with disabling and enabling instant run

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46999705/3117650) answer:

> Go to Android Studio Settings or Preferences (for MAC) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.
>
> Then deselect the "Enable Instant Run" checkbox at the top.

Comment: I have spent half a day trying to find that non existing bug, until I found your solution. Thank you a lot, man!

Comment: Same issue for me after upgrading to androidx. I have to leave instant run off.

Comment: check off, but signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR)

Comment: Hello i am using android studio 3.5.1 and i had tried almost a day to fix it but still i have the same issue, i have a google map in fragment and it work only first time when i installed app after that every time when i open app it give me a below

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xff3a200c in tid 15323 (FinalizerDaemon)

Comment: In the case of Android Studio 3.5 and above, you need to use option "Apply Changes". Try to enable and disable this option. It worked for me.

Answer (score 18):

Try disabling Android hardware acceleration in your manifest.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

Comment: it works but not a good solution at all !! stops all the animations and graphic things

Comment: i have the same issue but didn't work from my side, i used google map in fragment and when i open application it got crashed

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x3f000000 in tid 16591 (FinalizerDaemon)

i have tried almost a day, but didn't find the right solution for this, it working only few times then it gives an error

Comment: This also stops any mapbox maps from loading

Comment: This will also stop any camera streams you may have in your app.

Answer (score 11):

I've encountered this error when I tried to access the 'canvas' outside of `onDraw()`

```
    private Canvas canvas;

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        ....... }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) { 
            canvas.save(); // here
```

A very bad practice :/

Answer (score 5):

I was getting this error when using a bitmap like this:

```
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.myBitMap);
```

What fixed the problem for me was to reduce the size of the bitmap (>1000px high to 700px).

Comment: just use instead `BitmapOptions.inSampleSize`

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue in Android Studio when tried "Apply changes and restart Activity", since then the app wouldn't start. The reason was I tried this one may be inside the fragment or so, but I had to restart my phone which I used for testing my app, and then the issue was gone.

Answer (score 4):

I've faced with SIGSEGV on Android 4.4.4 (Nexuses, Samsungs)
And it turned out that fatal error was in parsing `null` `String` using `DecimalFormat`

```
 static DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("###,###.###");
 void someMethod(String value) {
...
    Number number = decimalFormat.parse(value);//value is null, SIGSEGV will happen`
...
}
```

On Android > 21 it was handled successfully with try/catch

Answer (score 4):

I faced this issue moment ago, after migrating from `android.support` to `androidx`.

The problem was `renderscript`.

Solution:
I removed from my `build.gradle` those two lines:

```
renderscriptTargetApi 21
renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
```

after that project building failed, because of unresolved references:

```
import androidx.renderscript.Allocation;
import androidx.renderscript.Element;
import androidx.renderscript.RenderScript;
import androidx.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
```

so I've changed them to:

```
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
```

After that all problems were gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using vitamio library and this fatal error occur.

Then make sure that in your project gradle targetSdkVersion must be less than 23.

Comment: Your solution works, But this could be a major problem as Play Store made in mandatory to set targetSdkversion to >=26 Aug 1st onwards.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (I am using Xamarin Forms) this error was thrown due to a binding error - e.g. :

```
<Label Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Start" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="10" TextColor="Pink" Text="{Binding }"></Label>
```

Basically I deleted the view model property by mistake. For Xamarin developers, if you have the same issue, check your bindings...

Answer (score 2):

If you had added some native C code in your project this answer could be helpful.

I had added some native C code in Android project.

Now I was trying to access that code which was returning native string to me, before processing the the string I had set its default value as nullptr. Now upon retrieving its value in Java code ran into this issue.

As our native C code is out from Java directory so getting no clue of exact line of code which is creating the issue. So I would suggest you to check your .cpp file and try to find any clue there.

Answer (score 2):

I've struggled this for hours and finally just went into the storage details of the app I'm debugging and did "clear data". It ran fine afterwards. In my case, it was some strange google services gms bug.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the issue was being caused by the Android Profiler. In Android Studio, click on "Android Profiler" and "end session".

Ironically, it was also causing extreme performance issues in the application.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue using **Flutter 2.8.1**.

I searched a lot but nothing helped me (disabling external packages I was using, debugging, invalidating cache, flutter clean, restart emulator, etc).

It turned out to be related to the work done in the `CustomPainter` class in my case. Even drawing a simple rectangle could end up in this kind of crash.

I switched to the beta channel (**Flutter 2.9.0-0.1.pre**) and the issue totally disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Check your JNI/native code. One of my references was null, but it was intermittent, so it wasn't very obvious.

Answer (score 0):

check your native functions,whether it is returning properly or not,If it is not returned please add return statements.

Answer (score 0):

For me that issue was due to a bad cast between two activities.
I recently moved this method from Activity1 to another 2. 
Doing so, the refactor left this explicit cast as it was before. 
So instead of doing

```
((Activity1) mainActivity).hideDialog();
```

I was supposed to do

```
((Activity2) mainActivity).hideDialog();
```

Note: But this error did not happen on android 8.0 I'm not yet sure why.

*** Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this segmentation fault error because of **Memory issues**.
My **struct** having many variables and arrays, had this Array of size 1024.

> Reducing the size to 512, the error was gone.

P.S: *This is a workaround and not a solution. 
It is necessary to find the struct size and **dynamic memory allocation**
is a better option.*

Comment: I'm having the same issue but it works in reverse. I'm storing up to 492 data in my array. If I set the size to like 512, the segfault error appears and closes my app, when I increase the size to like 1024 it does not appear. I'm having trouble understanding how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I used ViewTreeObserver inside `onDraw()` function.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // super.onDraw(canvas);
    ViewTreeObserver vto = mTextView.getViewTreeObserver();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // some animation        
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: I solved it by removing ViewTreeObserver from onDraw

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with a package that was added to my app (FancyShowCaseView) and caused this problem on pre-lolipop. that package was written in kotlin and my main codes were written in java. so now I'm checking version in pre-lolipop and don't let its class to be executed. temporary solved the problem.
check this out if you have similar problem like me

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue when I was creating a PDF using Android's PDF APIs and I accidentally used the canvas.save() and canvas.restore() after I had closed a pdf page.

Answer (score 0):

In my case when using PdfDocument API of android, the line `your_pdf_doc_object.finishPage(your_page)` should be at the end of the canvas drawer otherwise might create memory exceptions or memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

This error happens for me when i use [ics-openvpn](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn)

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdead0000 in tid 3548
```

Simply fix by adding "**x86**" to "**abiFilters**" like below

```
ndk {
   abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86", "x86_64"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on my code **Java on Android Studio**

I studied millions of page including all prior answers in this page. But I didn't find any useful answer.

Finally I checked all potential locations can raise the error.

This is my code before correction

```
surfaceView.draw(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r8);
```

and this is my code after correction that error disappeared.

```
synchronized (this) {
surfaceView.draw(r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r8);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem caused by SharedPreferences, I had two methods for saving data. One using editor.apply(), and another using editor.commit(). I changed both of them to editor.commit() and eveything went good.
Method 1

```
    private void saveId(int id) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("saved_id", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("bId", id);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Method 2

```
private void saveUserData(String saveName, String data){
    SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString(saveName,data);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone getting such an error in their Xamarin projects, it might be worth a try to pinpoint the interaction required to cause the issue (such as tapping a button) and put a try-catch block to get the managed exception from it. In my case, Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) error was caused originally by a managed C# exception that could be easily fixed. I don't understand why Xamarin doesn't report the managed exception to the debug output though.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I must find the `memory leak` in my fragment!

I user `profiler` of **android studio** and I find it finally from getting data from the **database**.

be aware of `Memory Leak`!

happy coding :)

Answer (score -2):

Add these two lines to your build.gradle in the android section:

```
android{
    compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility 1.8
            targetCompatibility 1.8
        }
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.