# OpenGL Causing Native Crash on Nexus 7

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, nexus-7, tegra

We have recently started beta testing our game through the play store. Nexus 7 users are reporting a crash on start, but I'm not sure how to debug it. That stacktrace in the dev console is shown below.

I am finding this particularly tricky to debug for two reasons,

1. I don't have physical access to a nexus 7
2. The stacktrace appears to show the crash occuring with libGLESv2_tegra.so, but its not giving me a line of java code to start from.

Can anyone give me some hints on how to debug this?

The game is 100% java, no NDK, and all the rendering is done with OpenGL ES 2.0

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000002c8
r0 d4e9d9e1 r1 671371c0 r2 00000068 r3 00000004
r4 67103008 r5 687a95d8 r6 687a953c r7 671371c0
r8 68843f98 r9 687a9680 sl 67103008 fp 6b2a4b24
ip 00000000 sp 6b2a48a0 lr 00000000 pc 686190e8 cpsr 600d0010
d0 0000000000000000 d1 0000000000000000
d2 0000000000000000 d3 0000000000000000
d4 000000003e97b426 d5 39da740e3f800000
d6 3f80000000000000 d7 0000000000000000
d8 3b80000000000000 d9 4316000040a5846a
d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
d16 0000000000000001 d17 0000000000000000
d18 0000000000000000 d19 0000000000000001
d20 0000000000004000 d21 0000000000000000
d22 0000000000004000 d23 0000000000000001
d24 0000000000000000 d25 3ff0000000000000
d26 3fce580000000000 d27 bfa1290447333348
d28 bfa1290447333346 d29 3e2d38fc57f240cc
d30 bfd151202d839000 d31 3fc54eae586af9ec
scr 20000010

backtrace:
#00 pc 000400e8 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#01 pc 00028614 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#02 pc 00028664 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#03 pc 000414a8 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#04 pc 00027400 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#05 pc 000269e4 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#06 pc 00029db4 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#07 pc 0000af94 /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_tegra.so
#08 pc 00006c89 /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
#09 pc 00008021 /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
#10 pc 000081bb /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
#11 pc 00006e73 /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
#12 pc 00006eb5 /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so
#13 pc 000077a9 /system/lib/egl/libEGL_tegra.so (eglDestroyContext+18)
#14 pc 0000f8b1 /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglDestroyContext+64)
#15 pc 000534eb /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#16 pc 0001ea50 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
#17 pc 0004f667 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
#18 pc 00027ee0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#19 pc 0002f3d8 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#20 pc 0002ca7c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
#21 pc 00061ae3 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+338)
#22 pc 00061b07 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#23 pc 000567f3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#24 pc 0000d248 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#25 pc 0000d3e0 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)

code around pc:
686190c8 e2833014 e1530000 1afffff9 e597e02c 
686190d8 e1a01007 e5852070 e3a03004 e59420ec 
686190e8 e59e02c8 eb0042e4 e3500000 e5850074 
686190f8 0a000027 e594c0e8 e3a01000 e59430ec 
68619108 e086210c ebff181e e59430ec e3a01000 
68619118 e1a00005 e585107c e5853078 eaffff2d 
68619128 e59f20a0 e1a00008 e08f1002 ebff9a61 
68619138 e1a00005 ebff17f1 e3a00000 eaffff25 
68619148 e59f3084 e08fe003 e585e064 eaffff8f 
68619158 e59fc078 e1a00008 e08f100c ebff9a55 
68619168 e59f306c e3000501 e3002401 e08f1003 
68619178 ebff3942 eaffffed e59f1058 e3000505 
68619188 e30023f5 e08f1001 ebff393c e1a00005 
68619198 eaffff10 e59fe040 e3000505 e3002447 
686191a8 e08f100e ebff3935 eaffffe0 e59f202c 
686191b8 e1a00008 e08f1002 ebff9a3e eaffffdb 

code around lr:
00000000 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000010 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000020 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000030 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000040 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000050 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000060 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000070 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000080 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
00000090 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000a0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000b0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000c0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000d0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000e0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff 
000000f0 ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff ffffffff
```

Comment: how do you initialize the glSurface / eglContext?

Comment: Check out the answer to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18507287/1007510