# Android 4.4.3 web view doesn't follow redirects anymore

Tags: android, debugging, android-webview

Our hybrid app uses web views and starting with android version 4.4.3 on of the web views do not render. The app tries to load a **HTTPS** web view and just stays there for about 50 seconds after which it throws an exception similar to this one [Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked). Obviously we went down the path suggested in this SO to not much avail.

With our experiments we have determined the following

1. The last HTTP request/response (which does the redirect) is same with version 4.4.2 and 4.4.3. We verify this in charles proxy.
2. After the redirect 4.4.2 creates the cart(SSL) request/response but 4.4.3 doesn't even create a request.
3. [Chrome remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging) is of no help, the inspect just shows a blank screen.
4. The version of the chrome browser on the device doesn't matter.
5. The redirect code we are using is 302.
6. All the previous android versions work alright

Though initially we thought its a lollipop/ART specific bug it doesn't look like that anymore. Any ideas on how should we proceed?

Actually crash happens at this location libwebviewchromium.so

Also the tombstone file is at - https://gist.github.com/prolificcoder/ebd82081b47640a3cae2

tombstone from device - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2a6a28b2ec976075f587

Logcat logs - https://slack-files.com/T02RAT9SZ-F0351N4NW-997f5c

Comment: could you add the native crash as well? I might be able to symbolize it for you.

Comment: ah, unfortunately it doesn't look like I have symbols for the emulator. Are you using the emulator with H/w acceleration enabled? Do you get a crash like this on a device?

Comment: I got the same crash on device or h/w acceleration enabled emulator

Comment: Could you upload the crash from the device? I have symbols for device builds but not emulator builds.

Comment: @marin.kosiba I uploaded tombstone above. Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the Note3 libwebviwewchromium.so doesn't match the one you can build from AOSP but the x86 one does, so here is the [symbolized stack](https://gist.github.com/marcinkosiba/48fa1378580454e52f8b).

Unfortunately it looks like you found a bug in Blink, the rendering engine used by the WebView. Whatever page you're trying to load seems to crash the WebView killing your app along with it. Could you verify that loading that particular URL in a different WebView (write a trivial WebView app or use a WebView-based browser) also crashes? If so then it would be ideal if you could share the URL or isolate the offending bit of HTML/CSS/JS and share that.

Comment: I spent about 5 hours on trying to create a sample repro but unsucessful so far. My attempts (with comment) are here - https://bitbucket.org/prolificcoder/webview/src  I am suspecting we are doing something wonky in the app. Thanks for all your help

Comment: @satyajit - if you're OK sharing the crashing .apk and repro steps I can create a restricted bug on the Chromium bug tracker. Restricted essentially means only Google employees (and you) will be able to see the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Ok turns out the solution for the problem is in the layout. We didn't have **android:orientation="vertical"** before and I think the crash is happening when webview is trying to fit everything in the narrow space and somewhere while rendering fonts the app crashes.

Another dev discovered this while trying to create a better repro and observed the lint warnings in the sample project, strangely enough these didn't show up in the original app

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/webView_holder"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:max="100" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

I don't know how this would help any other person but lesson learned is that a layout messup can cause problems down the line

Comment: @marcin.kosiba does this make any sense to you? Can a layout problem cause a crash in the new version of webviews?

Comment: The WebView should not crash regardless. You might get a rendering glitch or something but definitely not a crash. It would still be helpful to get to the bottom of this - did you manage to get a working (crashing :) repro?

Comment: No we didn't manage to get a crashing app. The layout was showing an error in this new app but perhaps not in old eclipse/android studio when our app was developed. Here is the bitbucket branch - https://bitbucket.org/prolificcoder/webview/branch/gdwebview and the commit line https://bitbucket.org/prolificcoder/webview/commits/0c4fbde083777e41b8465dab4dc142a4982e8eff?at=master#add-comment. I don't think the apk will help but if you think i will upload it.

Comment: Thanks! The interesting thing is the crash. The layout error isn't interesting by itself. Well, I'm glad you managed to resolve this and feel free to ping me should you hit this again!