# Android Crash on Launch - ANR - uirenderer::DisplayListRenderer

Tags: android, svg, crash, android-anr-dialog

I'm seeing quite a few Crash/ANR's in my google play dashboard.  This crash has just started over the last couple releases, and it's starting to reflect more and more in the reviews.  I'm at a loss as to how to debug it though.

```
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'Verizon/kltevzw/kltevzw:5.0/LRX21T/G900VVRU2BOE1:user/release-keys'
Revision: '14'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 17258, tid: 17258, name: com.mycompany.myapp >>> com.mycompany.myapp <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x70
r0 00000068 r1 beb40bc4 r2 beb40bc8 r3 00000001
r4 af8e6ba0 r5 beb40bc8 r6 af8e6bd4 r7 9c0fde90
r8 ffffffff r9 b4e07800 sl ffffffff fp 134890c0
ip b6703914 sp beb40bb8 lr b66ccf05 pc b6ccfe42 cpsr 80000030

backtrace:
#00 pc 0000fe42 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::VectorImpl::insertAt(unsigned int, unsigned int)+17)
#01 pc 0001ff01 /system/lib/libhwui.so
#02 pc 00021443 /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DisplayListRenderer::drawPath(SkPath const*, SkPaint const*)+10)
#03 pc 0007cee9 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#04 pc 000b2227 /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Break down of Android Versions:

```
Android 5.0:    186 86.9%
Android 5.1:    28  13.1%
```

Break down of Android Devices

```
Galaxy: 31
Moto: 5
Droid: 1
```

As far as recent changes that have anything to do with rendering, I am using the com.larvalabs.svgandroid.SVG library for rendering SVG assets; but I do have a similar app in production using the same exact code for rendering SVG assets and that app has none of these crashes.  I also updated the app removing all SVG assets that were not also in my 2nd app (thinking maybe it was an individual SVG).

Comment: To me, it looks like the crash is not happening in your app or in svg-android. It looks to be in the OS itself. You may want to try reporting this on the Android bugtracker, and see what they say. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180579

Comment: No response.  @PaulLeBeau any other suggestions for narrowing down the source?  Reviews are not very kind at the moment...

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any suggestions, other than trying to get the help of someone who can reproduce it reliably and send them test builds of your app.  Also, have you seen the answers in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked