# Can't launch application through Android Studio (logcat [DEAD])

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

For the last two days the app I'm working on is showing up as [DEAD] in logcat and when I try to launch the app through the run button in Android Studio all seems fine, except the app never start and leaves no error message in Android Studio, except for [DEAD]. Any idea what this is?

[image]

**Update:**
I have been able to remove the [DEAD] thing from the logcat by:

- Removing the app from the device
- Restarting the device (Should not have been this because it was just started befor it happened, but just in case)
- Invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio
- Re-run the app from the toolbar in Android Studio

This might help to get you going again, but my question stays.

What is this?

Why does it happen?

And whats the correct way of solving it?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: What do you mean by `Invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio`?

Comment: @AlexJolig go to File > Invalidate caches & restart... in the menu bar.

Comment: I have found this when I open Android Device Monitor or any external program that connects with adb to the device causes my android studio ADB to be "dead". When this happens I go to android tools (top menu) and disable adb integration then re-enable it.

Comment: Are you running on Windows or Mac? I had a Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro that came pre installed with some dumb app called "PhoneBuddy" that had an adb implementation built in. Sometimes, it would take over my device's ADB connection. I remember getting the same kind of errors as you are now. If you are running Windows, check your Task Manager running services for instances of ADB and make sure there is only one. If there is more than one, you may have found the issue. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Comment: I had the same problem but this answer solved it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60614478/13344938

Answer (score 6):

The above error is due to

> java.io.IOException

which causes the current adb-connection to disconnect and connect to the new adb-connection request made by another software .

```
java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

When you start an adb client, the client first checks whether there is an adb server process already running. If there isn't, it starts the server process. When the server starts, it binds to local TCP port 5037 and listens for commands sent from adb clients—all adb clients use port 5037 to communicate with the adb server.

The server then sets up connections to all running emulator/device instances. It locates emulator/device instances by scanning odd-numbered ports in the range 5555 to 5585, the range used by emulators/devices. Where the server finds an adb daemon, it sets up a connection to that port.
Note that each emulator/device instance acquires a pair of sequential ports — an even-numbered port for console connections and an odd-numbered port for adb connections.

Above information can also be seen from its documentation
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

When a new application uses the same connection,your Android studio app reports DEAD in logcat.
To resolve the issue,use the adb kill-server command

```
adb kill-server  //Terminates the adb server process.
```

and then rerun your application.

Answer (score 2):

It shows that you fully stopped your application from your device or May you are getting some errors and Unfortunately Stopping Application.

Just try to **unplug device** or **close emulator** and Connect again.

Answer (score 0):

My solution: replace the debugging equipment.
I've had this problem recently, and I've been struggling with it for a long time.
I use as 3.0, the computer i7+16G+ SSD, the configuration will not be a problem.
During the period, I tried to restart as, the computer, have no effect.The online method tried some, but it didn't work.
I always thought it was the as problem, and then I was able to debug the machine.
The debug phone is a 7.0 system. After root, it enters the adb shell and finds that the command line does not respond. The phone shell has been stuck and the card dies and the card dies.
The as run is going to be directly stuck there.
The key as interface is not clickable, and the bug should be given to as.

Comment: Not sure if this answers the question in any capacity.