# Dead Activity in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio

I am working on an Android App,
when I am trying to run the app it the android studio shows dead word in log cat [image: like this].
The emulator starts but and App works perfectly but what is the dead word comes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove this by

- Removing the app from the device
- Restarting the device (Should not have been this because it was just started befor it happened, but just in case)
- Invalidate caches and restart in Android Studio
- Re-run the app from the toolbar in Android Studio

This was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803618/cant-launch-application-through-android-studio-logcat-dead) question.