# Can't Run my android app. Android Studio shows is as DEAD

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm starting the android tutorial at udacity. This course consist on creating a weather app [sunshine](https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-ud853/l-1395568821/m-1643858572).  At the end of lesson 1 when I try to run my app, android studio marked it as DEAD.

[image]

I tried all the steps in a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803618/cant-launch-application-through-android-studio-logcat-dead) however the problem remain the same.  Here is the adb logs:

> DeviceMonitor: adb restarted
>   PropertyFetcher: ShellCommandUnresponsiveException getting properties for device emulator-5554: null
>   DeviceMonitor: ExecutionException getting info for device emulator-5554
>   DeviceMonitor: Adb rejected connection to client '14794': closed

Comment: It seems like ADB cannot connect to your device. Are you trying to run the application on an emulator or a real device?

Comment: I tried in both and got the same problem. When I access the app from the app icon in my device a message said "Unfortunately, Sunshine has stopped"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually rebuild my application and it works. I have no explanation . I guess  it has something  with Android studio.

Answer (score 4):

1. Remove your device (Samsung GT-I9060I) from USB.
2. Close Android Studio.
3. Open Task Manager and kill all processes named `adb.exe`.
4. Open Android Studio and wait until Gradle build is finished.
5. Connect your device as emulator again.
6. Run your app.

Btw, I also faced this issue a month ago, and those steps help me.

Answer (score 0):

The ADB still works unstable, and never mind which IDE are used Eclipse or new Android Studio. 
The workaround for this is to restart adb.
Type in console:

```
 adb kill-server

 adb start-server
 * daemon not running. starting it now at tcp:5037 *
 * daemon started successfully *
```

Usually, this is enough condition to solve the issue for some time.