# opensl es crash when pausing the player

Tags: android, android-ndk, opensl

Can someone please help me figure out the problem here":
I am using opensl es to play audio and it crashes when I try to pause the

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xbd32e932 in tid 17523 (Thread-4343)
```

and here is my code

```
if ((*bqPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(bqPlayerPlay, SL_PLAYSTATE_PAUSED) != SL_RESULT_SUCCESS) {
                    LOGE("couldn't pause the audio player");
                }
```

Comment: That error code usually means memory was accessed incorrectly. Somewhere a pointer is being de-referenced that thinks its something its not. Possible a `char *` without a null terminator at the end?

Comment: Thanks, but why is it crashing when I am trying to pause the opensl es player? I believe I found a solution so far. I initialized the opensl es player on the main thread... Not sure why that helped... I just compared my code with the example from google and the only difference was that they were initializing on the main thread and mine was on a different thread.

Comment: This answer should help you track it down - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked