# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) (code=1)

Tags: android

I have an issue with my Android code.
Randomly, when I call a new Activity, I have a fatal error (the application doesn't close properly).
It happens on some devices and never on others. It's ok on Galaxy S4 Mini (Kitkat), not on OnePlus two, not on Nexus 4 (Lollipop).

```
10-08 22:25:13.908: I/DEBUG(483): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***     *** *** *** *** ***
10-08 22:25:13.908: I/DEBUG(483): Build fingerprint: 'OnePlus/OnePlus2/OnePlus2:5.1.1/LMY47V/1436933040:user/release-keys'
10-08 22:25:13.909: I/DEBUG(483): Revision: '0'
10-08 22:25:13.909: I/DEBUG(483): ABI: 'arm64'
10-08 22:25:13.909: I/DEBUG(483): pid: 4505, tid: 4505, name: m.ari.tell  >>> com.ariase.tellme <<<
10-08 22:25:13.909: I/DEBUG(483): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xdf8d6e1940
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x0   000000df8d6e1940  x1   0000007f8d71e500  x2   ffffffffffffffc0  x3   000000000000000a
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000006  x6   000000df8d6e1940  x7   0000000000000001
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x8   0000000000000020  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000007f8d5d0200  x11  0000007f8d5d0200
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x12  0000007f8d5d0200  x13  0000007f8d5d0200  x14  0000000000000000  x15  0000000000000003
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x16  0000000000000049  x17  0000007fa4808000  x18  0000000000000057  x19  000000df8d6e1940
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x20  0000007f8d71e500  x21  0000000000000058  x22  0000007fa8228000  x23  0000007fa8228000
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x24  0000000000000001  x25  0000007fa82352d8  x26  0000000000000000  x27  0000000000000000
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     x28  0000000000000001  x29  0000007ff5f87a40  x30  0000007fa81d456c
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     sp   0000007ff5f87a40  pc   0000007fa8180960  pstate 0000000080000000
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483): backtrace:
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #00 pc 0000000000015960  /system/lib64/libc.so (memcpy+216)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #01 pc 0000000000069568  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_arena_ralloc+604)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #02 pc 0000000000078ad8  /system/lib64/libc.so (je_realloc+620)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #03 pc 000000000001524c  /system/lib64/libc.so (realloc+20)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #04 pc 0000000000011d98  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::SharedBuffer::editResize(unsigned long) const+132)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #05 pc 0000000000016b24  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::VectorImpl::_grow(unsigned long, unsigned long)+392)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #06 pc 0000000000016ca8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::VectorImpl::insertAt(void const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+52)
10-08 22:25:13.960: I/DEBUG(483):     #07 pc 0000000000032348  /system/lib64/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DisplayListRenderer::drawPatch(SkBitmap const*, android::Res_png_9patch const*, float, float, float, float, SkPaint const*)+80)
10-08 22:25:13.961: I/DEBUG(483):     #08 pc 00000000000c4d7c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so
10-08 22:25:13.961: I/DEBUG(483):     #09 pc 00000000013e2324  /data/dalvik-cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat
10-08 22:25:14.523: I/DEBUG(483): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_06
```

Does someone got an idea ? :(

**EDIT**
Problem has been solved. I use Gson to store an object of type Location in SharedPreferences. It causes a memory drain. Finally, I recreate my personnal object Location and it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)

Comment: I don't understand how to use the addr2line =/ Which ? on What ? my stack is different every time :(

Comment: i guess, mat be thats the issue because of 64 bit system

Comment: Oh interresting. Is there a way to fix it ? To force 32 bits ?