# Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 29092

Tags: java, android, android-animation, fatal-error

I'm try to play a loading animation on my loading screen, and I read somewhere that android doesn't support gifs so either you have to break in into frames and then play it or we can use the Movie class.

Heres the leading activity -

```
package com.myapp.mehul.login.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;

import com.myapp.mehul.login.MYGIFView;
import com.myapp.mehul.login.MainActivity;
import com.myapp.mehul.login.R;
import com.myapp.mehul.login.app.Constants;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import io.socket.client.IO;
import io.socket.client.Socket;
import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;


/**
 * Created by mehul on 2/6/16.
 */
public class LoadingScreen extends Activity {

    /** Duration of wait **/
    private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 1000;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private Socket mSocket;
    String you;
    String opponentId;
    String username;

    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket(Constants.CHAT_SERVER_URL);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(new MYGIFView(getApplicationContext()));
        //initialise the socket
        mSocket.connect();
        //call add user
        mSocket.emit("add user");
        //start a listener for opponent
        mSocket.on("opponent", onOpponent);
        //initialise the username
        username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
    }

    private Emitter.Listener onOpponent = new Emitter.Listener(){
        @Override
        public  void call(final Object... args){
            LoadingScreen.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];

                    try {
                        you = data.getString("you");
                        opponentId = data.getString("opponent");
                        Log.d("LoadingScreen", data.toString());


                        //setResult(RESULT_OK, i);


                        finish();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        return;
                    }
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("opponentId", opponentId);
                    i.putExtra("you", you);
                    i.putExtra("username", username);
                    Log.d("goToChat", username);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoadingScreen.this);
        builder.setMessage("I knew you didn't have BALLS.").setCancelable(
                false).setPositiveButton("I am a LOSER",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //send the logout information to the server
                        JSONObject discon = new JSONObject();
                        try {
                            discon.put("opponent", opponentId);
                            discon.put("you", you);
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mSocket.emit("discon", discon);
                        mSocket.disconnect();

                        //finish the current activity.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(LoadingScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        LoadingScreen.this.finish();

                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("I'll fkin face it",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

}
```

In the above code I've set content view by passing it an instance of MYGIFView.class -

Heres MYGIFView.class

```
package com.myapp.mehul.login;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by mehul on 2/7/16.
 */
public class MYGIFView extends View{
    Movie movie,movie1;

    InputStream is=null,is1=null;

    long moviestart;
    public MYGIFView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        is=context.getResources().openRawResource(+ R.drawable.loading);

        movie=Movie.decodeStream(is);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        long now=android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        System.out.println("now="+now);
        if (moviestart == 0) { // first time
            moviestart = now;

        }
        System.out.println("\tmoviestart="+moviestart);
        int relTime = (int)((now - moviestart) % movie.duration()) ;
        System.out.println("time="+relTime+"\treltime="+movie.duration());
        movie.setTime(relTime);
        movie.draw(canvas,this.getWidth()/2-20,this.getHeight()/2-40);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

The loading activity IS creating an instance of MYGIFView.class and it logs the data but then it gives fatal signal 11. I tried to search but I didn't get any answer.

console log -

```
02-07 12:22:30.321 29092-29092/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-07 12:22:30.341 29092-29102/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active

02-07 12:22:30.422 29092-29092/? D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {username=Harsh}
02-07 12:22:30.422 29092-29092/? D/LoginActivity: already logged in
02-07 12:22:30.425 29092-29092/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.myapp.mehul.login time:71360781
02-07 12:22:30.487 29092-29092/? D/MainMenu: painted again
02-07 12:22:30.490 29092-29092/? D/SQLiteHandler: Fetching user from Sqlite: {username=Harsh}
02-07 12:22:30.554 29092-29149/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
02-07 12:22:30.559 29092-29092/? D/Atlas: Validating map...
02-07 12:22:30.596 29092-29149/? I/Adreno-EGL: <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030_msm8974_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
                                               OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
                                               Build Date: 04/15/15 Wed
                                               Local Branch: mybranch9068252
                                               Remote Branch: quic/LA.BF.1.1.1_rb1.19
                                               Local Patches: NONE
                                               Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.BF.1.1.1_RB1.05.01.00.042.030 +  NOTHING
02-07 12:22:30.597 29092-29149/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
02-07 12:22:30.611 29092-29149/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-07 12:22:30.660 29092-29092/? I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@387f1572 time:71361016
02-07 12:22:31.898 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login D/go to chat: was called
02-07 12:22:31.899 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.myapp.mehul.login time:71362255
02-07 12:22:31.997 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login I/System.out: now=71362353
02-07 12:22:31.997 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login I/System.out:  moviestart=71362353
02-07 12:22:31.997 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login I/System.out: time=0   reltime=1850
02-07 12:22:32.007 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 29092 (app.mehul.login)
02-07 12:22:32.541 29092-29092/com.myapp.mehul.login W/app.mehul.login: type=1701 audit(0.0:302): auid=4294967295 uid=10250 gid=10250 ses=4294967295 subj=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 reason="memory violation" sig=11
```

Comment: This is a memory related error. You may have a memory leak or out of memory in your device.

Comment: This answer might be useful for you. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I received a batch for this question which means its being viewed a lot, so I'll answer this question -

What I figured out was the line below was throwing the error -

```
movie.draw(canvas,this.getWidth()/2-20,this.getHeight()/2-40);
```

Now the problem is that this error specifically can be caused by lots of reasons, its never a specific reason.. the reason mine wasn't working out was because my device didn't work well with hardware acceleration, so I just had to disable it in the manifest application, like this -

```
<android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
```

Now its possible that the reason might not be the same....but the core reason is the same, its memory related, and most chances are its a bug in the firmware of the device or emulator you are testing upon.

Comment: Setting the hardware acceleration fixed the issue but it wasn't acceptable for my application. So I disabled the hardware acceleration for the specific view only. textView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

Comment: You saved my life, but i really need hardware acceleration to render shadows, and am missing any workaround :-( but on some devices, h/ware acceleration works well and fail when i test the app on Samsung devices.

Answer (score 16):

In the Manifest set in your activity :

```
    <activity
        android:name="LoadingScreen"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
    </activity>
```

Comment: tnx alot. it help me . tnx again

Answer (score 1):

I got here with the exact same problem but in React Native, so I will put a solution for those who need it too. The error may be triggered by [react-native-webview](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/) and/or [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). In some cases, like me, you don't want to disable Hardware Acceleration on the whole app, so here's a workaround:

react-native-webview

```
<WebView
  androidHardwareAccelerationDisabled
  source={source}
/>
```

React Navigation 5

```
<NavigationContainer>
     <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="HomeScreen">
          <Stack.Screen
            name="HomeScreen"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              animationEnabled: false,
            }}
          />
     </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/575