# A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1)

Tags: android, android-service, segmentation-fault, telegram

I am trying to run telegram. In my LogCat this error appears:

```
A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 1768 (m.telegram.beta
```

My logcat:

```
 I/dalvikvm﹕ | schedstat=( 181904898 336868213 182 ) utm=10 stm=8 core=0
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #00  pc 0008f4ad  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #01  pc 00073efa  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #02  pc 00074024  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #03  pc 0003879a  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #04  pc 0003d6b8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ #05  pc 000c7fa9    /data/data/telegram.beta/lib/libtmessages.20.so
 I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
 I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:368)
 I/dalvikvm﹕ at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
 A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 1768 (m.telegram.beta)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked

Answer (score 1):

Just find select `org.telegram.messenegr` in spinner of Android Monitor section.