# Unable to track the Crash in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks, crash-reports

I am developing an android app. I got one weird issue while testing my app.

My app is `crashing` randomly at any moment showing this dialog:

```
"Unfortunately XYX app has stopped"
```

When I tracked the logs I got this one:

```
  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdbc in tid 11744 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

Native Libraries Used:

```
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar')
```

I am unable to fix this bug. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything useful.

**I developing in API version 8-22.**

Comment: Are you using some native libraries?

Comment: @EricB. yes I am using some native libraries I have Updated the question. And I am using nested Fragments .

Comment: What i meant was, are you using any C/C++ libraries?

Comment: No i am not using that

Comment: What device are you testing on?

Comment: I have tested on Moto-G(API-level-23) , Nexus 5-(API-level-22) and Lenovo A600Plus(API-level-21)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107819/discussion-between-eric-b-and-nsuser).

Comment: I am not able to find what is the causing this memory issues or use of nested fragments

Comment: Check similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked