# Android WebView cause application to crash with Fatal Signal SIGSEGV 11

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a view that is having a webview which is loading a chart from the server. The chart displays differently for different data.

So I have a list which displays different analysis types and when you click on the analysis item it will take to the chartview which is the fragment with webview.

Now while switching back and forth rapidly the webview causes the application to crash SIGSEGV 11.

Here is the crash dump

```
04-27 10:47:41.918 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
04-27 10:47:41.918 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: V WebView:49.0.2623.105
04-27 10:47:41.918 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: O A arm64 08 aarch64 samsung/zeroltetmo/zeroltetmo:6.0.1/MMB29K/G925TUVU3EPD1:user/release-keys
04-27 10:47:41.918 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: G OpenGL ES 3.1 v1.r7p0-03rel0.b596bd02e7d0169c10574b57180c8b57|ARM|Mali-T760
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000005586804000 0000000000000000 0000000000004000 0A952470EFA1E00762A32B1C17CBCC010 app_process64
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7DBBF000 0000000000000000 0000000000017000 DC97718AFE68A1EEFE1E3673F0A2233A0 gralloc.exynos5.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F7E605000 0000000000000000 000000000193E000 E17C790D49C6EDC762A70EB956F6A37C0 libGLES_mali.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F80B01000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 A0F9C17514253794C92F9F2382A26E400 libion.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F81010000 0000000000000000 000000000019D000 382A0B32C3BACC202D2B6D9BAC6039E40 libgmscore.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F8120A000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 20CD8CA0BD22CE81D1A01F1E3EB9912C0 libwebviewchromium_plat_support.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F88168000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 7EDB67509FEFD609226D70ECD24D0C8D0 libknoxvpnfdsender.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F887C9000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 EA000ACD5C940A9B5B91EADE96554BA50 libconscrypt_gmscore_jni.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F8C348000 0000000000000000 00000000030A0000 8D0CEF0580F43861E46BB5DB5DD680770 libwebviewchromium.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92A84000 0000000000000000 0000000000021000 E37B03B5C58E716859C9AC3CFF4C72400 libstagefright_amrnb_common.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92A9B000 0000000000000000 0000000000054000 C486428A8C01722BF447C69946AC5C870 libexif.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92AEF000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 4B876B3E8FB9D5391118BBA7307D54FA0 libjhead.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92B0D000 0000000000000000 0000000000032000 98767DCF5FB80E07BAA67819D52DB80F0 libmtp.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F92B37000 0000000000000000 0000000000088000 B239309682AAABF6EF8B394F6FF9B09C0 libmedia_jni.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F95917000 0000000000000000 0000000000038000 BA979F3380071903BF7B095679FD3F4F0 libkeymaster1.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9594F000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 6B08D1DEED41C154990E5E7365C4E59D0 libkeymaster_messages.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9596A000 0000000000000000 0000000000032000 DA5BB454F14A516FD3888F3F0939FE7A0 libsoftkeymasterdevice.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9599C000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 33D82D345171D7FBC47409B3E7E9151C0 libtlc_direct_comm.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F959C9000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 DF3432320C958EEF601406B520E371E40 libtlc_proxy_comm.so
04-27 10:47:41.928 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F959E8000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 7D30C28CB5ABA716E374ED9F00044F540 libtlc_comm.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F96095000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 7A50E60510099AAB3BBFEA2BB9DC49F10 libskia_opt.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F976CA000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 FC4238B9608D3ED643DAAE4747DC3A0F0 libwebviewchromium_loader.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9772B000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 94A819254E171B5BA7595E30A00B94120 libcompiler_rt.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F97851000 0000000000000000 000000000001F000 75D3201105F1E0FCA346D2B87BD3472C0 libMcClient.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9786E000 0000000000000000 0000000000023000 C756F5889EDC13013C67C1590DCE8CDA0 libkeystore_binder.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F97891000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 829463E88049EFED1231F59375A45E920 libtlc_tz_dcm.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F978A9000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 3F706D075C03891FC3BC87401C8F5C900 libkeystore-engine.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F978BD000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 3A720FDF47DF03B59C4EABF1FB66F85A0 libdcm_engine.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F978D0000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 119DCC755C536FADE45A0501D32ED3B70 libucsengine.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F978E8000 0000000000000000 0000000000021000 DACF654DA26CBAD186DCD8CB0FC4D0690 libsecpkcs11_engine.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F97906000 0000000000000000 000000000003A000 CDF64A4F91AC40F6EAA5509B3C3245490 libjavacrypto.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F97C59000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 4725A628287A2951954EE553551A3AA80 memtrack.exynos5.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F99709000 0000000000000000 000000000006D000 0D8E60BE26476590D3471F80B2BDA56E0 libjavacore.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9DA0C000 0000000000000000 0000000000631000 F1B7522D96D567694AD4F71CC65E9FFF0 libart.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E32F000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 41A75C7C6170E6E7AA104D621CA8F92E0 libjnigraphics.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9E2A6000 0000000000000000 0000000001063000 2D3262D8FF03CDA6BC7BEE536A9BBC6B0 libLLVM.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F317000 0000000000000000 000000000005C000 235AB33981002F89775F9EE49038644A0 libbcinfo.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F372000 0000000000000000 0000000000074000 6BD7FBA11D7F50E8D07D61751076DB850 libbcc.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F3E6000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 62997FAF049AC3C7AFAAD85860E2D4DB0 lib_SamsungVAD_v01009.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F3F8000 0000000000000000 0000000000025000 36A4CF43C2E172FFECAB29B4D9C928790 libcommon_time_client.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F41D000 0000000000000000 0000000000035000 24EFD57092A11F31120834E4961C80DE0 libprotobuf-cpp-lite.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F453000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 A29333B10A4EB84D6FA01AF53EC36A190 libsec_km.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F46F000 0000000000000000 000000000009C000 A3D10D38DFE52619C085454CABB540C30 libmorpho_hyperlapse_interface.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F508000 0000000000000000 0000000000038000 5ECBB229243E59C473274F230FAAF3B10 libsensorservice.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F53E000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 37052D479AA0647C24F1BE2FB67C361F0 libandroid.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F566000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 FEC83618BA8A49A0E29179064AD9F5FA0 libSEF4MP4.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F57A000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 2F14423BDFD038F5B9703C146EE614170 libSEF.so
04-27 10:47:41.938 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F5A2000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 63CB68C81C29E7764F63EDC6F6F544F70 libsfextcp.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F5BE000 0000000000000000 0000000000070000 EBAB48DB141449709BD8BBD8BAA6AFDB0 libsavsff.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F635000 0000000000000000 0000000000076000 4E190F75D1CE2AC5CA812CAC0ED06C3E0 libsavscmn.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F6AB000 0000000000000000 000000000008D000 5FBBA189A9980BB4D092F1766963E4C70 libomafldrm.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F738000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 549A0BAAA84CE101CAEAE1943D1C56F70 libstagefright_avc_common.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F753000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 9830F4E348D4196FB7F294A1FE4FB97C0 libstagefright_enc_common.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F765000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 EE2A0434CF3E1BF1BCA10A67FAF1B1220 libpowermanager.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F77A000 0000000000000000 000000000002E000 E3E20AB41FF05AAA0F073CC8681885B20 libvorbisidec.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F7A8000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 79D5E314B10C4CB69D1F764BED800B290 libstagefright_yuv.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F7B6000 0000000000000000 0000000000046000 3C5736AFE3DEF1AA27F272BC28F88F670 libstagefright_omx.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F7FC000 0000000000000000 000000000005D000 9131AEE72B5297A8CADEAC648E4B11930 libopus.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F859000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 B4616297EF89E02EF2CD7BE2E29696280 libmediautils.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F86E000 0000000000000000 0000000000039000 6B75EF510E860738C1CCC794DE0466DA0 libdrmframework.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F8A8000 0000000000000000 000000000003B000 8DEC887D2927A73804563DA75FAA8BDF0 libRScpp.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F8E0000 0000000000000000 0000000000069000 E1530C3A095C6849F146F53D57EE1D950 libRS.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F94A000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 5D450D1288721387C35537689F4806610 libspeexresampler.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F95E000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 89F7355588E2EED3A90C220871A7194E0 libsamsungvad.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F96F000 0000000000000000 0000000000019000 CD0D74C5EF0C8130DD7D7E57735CEB620 libedmnativehelper.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F988000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 74480A20995516D83ECAEFA59F80E4830 libnbaio.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9F9A6000 0000000000000000 0000000000126000 4469DBB5374EF1B7DE424748186B6B990 libcrypto-rename.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FACC000 0000000000000000 000000000002B000 C5C21B8E1DAF594E90719CD15AB79A110 libpcre.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FAF7000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 E6444C209E79FA09DA2951E4CA43C3B30 libwpa_client.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FB0A000 0000000000000000 00000000000D3000 05BBAC18028CE3BD9CC7BF36C749D5D40 libGLES_trace.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FBDD000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 63264F1F9D5559ADCAD2BD5C352908960 libsdp_crypto.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FBF5000 0000000000000000 0000000000018000 A3602DD300F7178553106FF0F6622DB00 libfimg.so
04-27 10:47:41.948 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FC0D000 0000000000000000 0000000000098000 8C318A3F7B690CFEB194704DAB9D015A0 libAstcEnc.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FCC4000 0000000000000000 0000000000030000 C83F9899267D112726025DA6C8215F630 libquramimagecodec.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FCF3000 0000000000000000 000000000007D000 CFE0C5FA97B1A9255ED2B95C0C6126140 libft2.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FD70000 0000000000000000 0000000000046000 473B18B275BF5059D0B6E80A2D1AAB330 libpng.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FDB4000 0000000000000000 000000000001E000 CB2D8B7D773688C00D70CC9F4F19D11A0 libremotedesktop_client.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FDD2000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 B0DF4A52401CBD235AEF16AC628EA3D60 libsync.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FDE4000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 A9D8F0FC99E2B43DA9C7B48064C099E60 libstdc++.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FDFA000 0000000000000000 000000000002C000 8EF100959AF09F572125F3FC32C316480 libunwind.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FE8F000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 5A9E8F483A1ECF87BB936CA4948047760 libbase.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FEA9000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 DDF0E09D9CD64DD9D39A5B8E5BB1F6DB0 libeffects.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FEBF000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 8D5CF80B454C06CF42A5BD4EBA4F88110 libstagefright_http_support.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FED1000 0000000000000000 0000000000032000 263C78A91D5F1E19BCD33F14340D6C8F0 libstagefright_foundation.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007F9FEE4000 0000000000000000 0000000000268000 D5F3CE721452A0AF395279A20C8DD9870 libstagefright.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA014C000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 492662D916F97F6E900CFC4E7438C3600 libpersona.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0161000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 EF1C620E6707912AC93719190428350E0 libimagefilter.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0189000 0000000000000000 0000000000053000 7500CBEFEAD2A9E9CD992FBCDC1508D40 libsecure_storage.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA01DD000 0000000000000000 0000000000030000 C1D44CED5DA63B2B0BBA42EA1947E3B80 libsamsungeffect.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA020D000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 59F5A3585E2A8F6761F5ECC3D47A32FC0 libSEC_EGL.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA021F000 0000000000000000 0000000000020000 CF88539E32CAE76B7F337F940DE1F38F0 libsensorhub.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0240000 0000000000000000 0000000000035000 A5EF980E77D585DB5C0A0E070D11BC4C0 libmctraster.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0275000 0000000000000000 00000000000C1000 B7A6AE22801858AB281D169EEFA209F90 libhwui.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0336000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 D5F2F80FE66FB1C569CF12A7A06DCA5E0 libcc_manager.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0348000 0000000000000000 0000000000016000 22DE6F86CD1B5392EADC381084479C0F0 libsecnativefeature.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA035E000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 E64931E488CCE2EA118F8187EBA0C2FD0 libradio_metadata.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0371000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 BC200C15AA7D37AF416A36CE0DCCF9430 libnativebridge.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0385000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 34798069D08B1CCC46B4F2C1764D05B70 libprocessgroup.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0399000 0000000000000000 0000000000027000 9DAEB94E9CDB7D643B9E6FD6131F0B320 libminikin.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA03BC000 0000000000000000 0000000000022000 DF07F9231CF3A19AF420C5DD8C16683F0 libsoundtrigger.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA03DA000 0000000000000000 0000000000023000 5CC7B8D3CA8138D4FB59E76BCE8D269C0 libradio.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA03FD000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 0E6ACA6EB7FDC1E523F3F29B26FE4AA80 libnetd_client.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA040F000 0000000000000000 0000000000026000 F5EB3CB81AE075712E885CDDC34993090 libimg_utils.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0420000 0000000000000000 000000000045E000 7AE3247E1E0C58E28968E2F11858D0880 libpdfium.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA087F000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 2E40610C3B8EC7590EF6FE14BEA1C32A0 libaudioutils.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA089B000 0000000000000000 000000000002D000 7D393D58667C77CEB28215470BB326A00 libz.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA08C9000 0000000000000000 0000000000061000 048E02A7541034FEFE2F27F39FFBC3860 libharfbuzz_ng.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA092A000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 83FF93AF1BD9B0243591E2E23F55B3CC0 libusbhost.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA093F000 0000000000000000 0000000000048000 145C74EAE43C803992B14FB30C940FDA0 libjpeg.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0928000 0000000000000000 0000000000180000 B016E8DAE969447CD4A468594D3BD4630 libmedia.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0A8E000 0000000000000000 000000000025B000 FB4097AC30D111FE172F281EC4700D8E0 libicui18n.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0CD0000 0000000000000000 00000000001C0000 905D2802D16B21C9BBD32C70ECBC80100 libicuuc.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0E94000 0000000000000000 000000000004D000 F9BCAE802A6A53014D599952E0E4F43B0 libssl.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA0EE1000 0000000000000000 000000000012C000 78FD047C33A1420977265774D7CAFC1F0 libcrypto.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA100F000 0000000000000000 000000000006A000 FE93FB6C5BDD9D305F39ACF76F261AEE0 libsonivox.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA107A000 0000000000000000 000000000002D000 8CC8A51CD81790ED1087D6CFB283D6C20 libselinux.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA10A8000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 27C11F773207EF14D33FCE7A258DF2890 libhardware_legacy.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA10C3000 0000000000000000 0000000000014000 3FC84A09E5DEBF0E0C86D5A8AF7DD7D20 libhardware.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA10D7000 0000000000000000 0000000000015000 496AB0E9C2AE762E21CCCD659954E91F0 libETC1.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA10EC000 0000000000000000 0000000000025000 4D536885ECB23BFB0E3F9B953FEE4D240 libGLESv2.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1111000 0000000000000000 000000000001D000 30CEF85BDA2544921F6E39D46FCCCD700 libGLESv1_CM.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1115000 0000000000000000 0000000000109000 744BC9904AE971E8F2CA27F973223C1A0 libEGL.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1221000 0000000000000000 00000000000F7000 B9EA918D68EED215B2ACCB92679C60310 libsqlite.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA12D8000 0000000000000000 0000000000602000 B907053F4AE7E190DB7405867F03E6BF0 libskia.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA18E2000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 B0117BF5A0B00A0FFBACB77C7DBFCF640 libcamera_metadata.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA18F0000 0000000000000000 000000000006A000 404AFF5F584583FBEC8309CCC0D7BD220 libcamera_client.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1955000 0000000000000000 0000000000083000 E296EF808ABA5178496E9A1EEAE9C5BC0 libinputflinger.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA19D0000 0000000000000000 0000000000045000 B07EB03FC9DE1D178579E1C25172A97A0 libinput.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA19F2000 0000000000000000 00000000000B5000 A85D28816EEE96FA674F97232C1B2AD20 libgui.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1AA7000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 17574A71973DA021F380FA01115C64450 libui.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1ABA000 0000000000000000 000000000001B000 7E301A24D026CE5F205B6AB70547518B0 libnetutils.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1AD5000 0000000000000000 0000000000019000 DB44324D39BE1EAC2EAA8A36B18C60FD0 libnativehelper.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1AEE000 0000000000000000 0000000000034000 0DA2A0484B19BCBAB8B408BDB2CABA860 libexpat.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1B21000 0000000000000000 0000000000050000 B1F0AF408A426A4169715DCDE0F6D8D00 libandroidfw.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1B71000 0000000000000000 0000000000013000 20C0C014B27692BFDD04F35C2C3EF0D00 libmemtrack.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1B84000 0000000000000000 000000000001C000 6FCC5354B757803A5B6D56E8B4C740E30 libbacktrace.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1BA0000 0000000000000000 000000000004A000 6AB28E64EF49FBDC377CF17DEBC979FF0 libm.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1BEA000 0000000000000000 00000000000DA000 357D10D8CB3C40FE367C0714A7633E150 libc.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1CCA000 0000000000000000 00000000000F7000 0E25F57E88DC043EE850CBF894E3444E0 libc++.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1DBF000 0000000000000000 000000000005B000 0F9B31FC288EC10A3C7FA058048107FB0 libwilhelm.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1DEB000 0000000000000000 00000000001C3000 392077930FA392AE61E6B33F8BE27ECC0 libandroid_runtime.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA1FA2000 0000000000000000 0000000000060000 825A632C7C2E1552D9E299436686AF290 libbinder.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2002000 0000000000000000 000000000001A000 98B21B9F6A246D62D8DBD67AC6C869F20 liblog.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA201C000 0000000000000000 0000000000037000 1EAEBD73BF1D84EE65D03C0C8A548C300 libutils.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA2053000 0000000000000000 0000000000028000 FFD85F6CDAE40A5ACA555AF0BDCBF4980 libcutils.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA207D000 0000000000000000 0000000000012000 23E29BC4ABC57F0DF4908B113E79C93E0 libsigchain.so
04-27 10:47:41.958 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA20AF000 0000000000000000 0000000000031000 3A5951EE8A1C2280717C8A907F31B8D00 linker64
04-27 10:47:41.968 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: M 0000007FA20EE000 0000000000000000 0000000000002000 672B2CD6CF8AF6C45BD70F2AB02B3D0C0 linux-gate.so
04-27 10:47:41.968 13094 13094 F google-breakpad: -----END BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----


04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: Chrome build fingerprint:
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: 16.03.1_00_009_dbg
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: 1603100009
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: 3667b129-cfef-4249-a5ea-64d26fb9c0a5
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 W google-breakpad: ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ### ###
04-27 10:47:41.988 11609 12016 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 12016 (AsyncServer)


04-27 10:47:42.028  3488  4903 D InputMethodManagerService: windowGainedFocus mCurrentFocusedUserId - 0 and mSecureKeypadEnabled-false
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zeroltetmo/zeroltetmo:6.0.1/MMB29K/G925TUVU3EPD1:user/release-keys'
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : Revision: '10'
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm64'
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : pid: 11609, tid: 12016, name: AsyncServer  >>> com.tradingtechnologies.ntm <<<
04-27 10:47:42.048  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x20
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x0   0000000000000000  x1   0000000000000001  x2   0000000000000000  x3   0000000000000000
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   0000000000000000
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x8   0000000000000001  x9   0000000000000000  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000040
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x12  0000000000000000  x13  00000000000012d8  x14  0000000000026230  x15  0000000000000c0d
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x16  0000000000000000  x17  0000000000000000  x18  0000007f8118a598  x19  0000000000000000
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x20  0000007f881c6a80  x21  00000000ffffffff  x22  0000007f7b608d00  x23  0000000000000000
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x24  0000007f881c6a80  x25  000000007b90700c  x26  0000007f95a084a0  x27  000000000000eb20
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     x28  0000007f9e028788  x29  0000007f79e7ec10  x30  0000007f8106f398
04-27 10:47:42.078  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     sp   0000007f79e7ec10  pc   0000007f81090740  pstate 0000000060000000
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : 
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000000000080740  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libgmscore.so
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 000000000005f394  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libgmscore.so
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 0000000000044d30  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/lib/arm64/libgmscore.so
04-27 10:47:42.088  3069  3069 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 0000000004294ba4  /data/app/com.google.android.gms-2/oat/arm64/base.odex (offset 0x2901000)
04-27 10:47:42.648  3488  3499 I art     : Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5193(291KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 19% free, 66MB/82MB, paused 2.546ms total 250.897ms
04-27 10:47:42.778  4177  4177 D Recents : onTaskStackChanged
```

This is what i see everytime.

Comment: This is what I am getting :  A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x20 in tid 7008 (AsyncServer)

Comment: I think its not an error of `WebView`, are you using any `native library`? And possible duplicate of [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)

Answer (score 0):

I did solved this problem by moving memory allocation (likes `new byte[]`) from in thread to in class.

I don't know well, I found that thread heap is related with native memory. If you are using a thread, try it.