# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 16163 , how to fix this?

Tags: android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow

The issue I'm having is that, the application I'm developing is running till *Lollipop* version and now when I trying to run an application on *Marshmallow* my application is getting crash and the log I getting are as follow :

> 05-12 11:22:34.402 848-978/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0
>   {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER]
>   flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute/.SplashII (has
>   extras)} from uid 10008 on display 0 05-12 11:22:34.443 16163-16163/?
>   I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni 0
>       5-12 11:22:34.449
>   848-860/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc
>   16163:com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute/u0a83 for activity
>   com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute/.SplashII 05-12 11:22:34.455 505-876/?
>   D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf1d80000) throttle end: throttle time(8) 05-12
>   11:22:34.482 16163-16168/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active 05-12
>   11:22:34.513 16163-16163/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1,
>   fault addr 0x0 in tid 16163 (mobile.aceroute) 05-12 11:22:34.614
>   104-104/? A/DEBUG: *****            
>      05-12 11:22:34.614 104-104/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'Android/vbox86p/vbox86p:6.0/MRA58K/buildbot01102000:userdebug/test-keys'
>   05-12 11:22:34.614 104-104/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0' 05-12 11:22:34.614
>   104-104/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86' 05-12 11:22:34.614 104-104/? A/DEBUG:
>   pid: 16163, tid: 16163, name: mobile.aceroute  >>>
>   com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute <<< 05-12 11:22:34.614 104-104/? A/DEBUG:
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 05-12
>   11:22:34.621 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx f77469c0  ecx
>   00000000  edx 00000000 05-12 11:22:34.621 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     esi
>   f3e19a80  edi 00000000 05-12 11:22:34.621 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     xcs
>   00000023  xds 0000002b  xes 0000002b  xfs 00000007  xss 0000002b 05-12
>   11:22:34.621 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     eip f732c442  ebp 12c6f280  esp
>   fff7f21c  flags 00210283 05-12 11:22:34.629 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     #00
>   pc 0001e442  /system/lib/libc.so (strlen+18) 05-12 11:22:34.630
>   104-104/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 0001322b  /system/lib/libutils.so
>   (android::String16::String16(char const)+29) 05-12 11:22:34.630
>   104-104/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 0004172d  /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
>   05-12 11:22:34.630 104-104/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 720eff30 
>   /data/dalvik-cache/x86/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x1eb9000)
>   05-12 11:22:34.637 1116-1345/com.android.launcher3 E/Surface:
>   getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xdec7bcd0 05-12 11:22:34.742
>   104-104/? E/DEBUG: AM write failed: Broken pipe 05-12 11:22:34.742
>   848-865/system_process I/BootReceiver: Copying
>   /data/tombstones/tombstone_04 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE) 05-12
>   11:22:34.757 848-16180/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force
>   finishing activity com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute/.SplashII 05-12
>   11:22:34.780 503-503/? I/Zygote: Process 16163 exited due to signal
>   (11) 05-12 11:22:34.783 826-826/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 826:
>   eglCreateSyncKHR(1215): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE) 05-12
>   11:22:34.898 848-16180/system_process W/ActivityManager: Exception
>   thrown during pause
>                                                                  android.os.DeadObjectException
>                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
>                                                                      at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:503)
>                                                                      at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:727)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:867)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2907)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2763)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2755)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11971)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11867)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12556)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:12063)
>                                                                      at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
>   05-12 11:22:34.941 848-1160/system_process I/ActivityManager: Process
>   com.aceroute.mobile.aceroute (pid 16163) has died 05-12 11:22:34.992
>   848-867/system_process W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
>                                                              java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@bbc7de0 does not exist
>                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8733)
>                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8724)
>                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2697)
>                                                                  at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:187)
>                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3099)
>                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5606)
>                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3409)
>                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
>                                                                  at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 05-12
>   11:22:35.035 848-1719/system_process I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized
>   EGL, version 1.4 05-12 11:22:35.041 1116-1345/com.android.launcher3
>   W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 05-12 11:22:35.041
>   1116-1345/com.android.launcher3 W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set
>   EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe06b6dc0, error=EGL_SUCCESS 05-12
>   11:22:35.103 848-1719/system_process W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib
>   not implemented 05-12 11:22:35.103 848-1719/system_process
>   W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface
>   0xd972c800, error=EGL_SUCCESS 05-12 11:22:37.435
>   848-1719/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown
>   buffer: 0xf2cf5c60 05-12 11:22:37.437 848-1719/system_process
>   D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xdeed2280
>   (RippleDrawable) with handle 0xdbb22df0 05-12 11:22:37.441
>   848-1160/system_process W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already
>   focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@c3b1c3c
>   attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@5926644 05-12
>   11:22:37.475 505-876/? D/AudioFlinger: mixer(0xf1d80000) throttle end:
>   throttle time(15) 05-12 11:22:37.689 848-867/system_process W/AppOps:
>   Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0
>   duration=0 nesting=0 05-12 11:23:02.221 100-100/? D/Genyd: Received
>   Set Clipboard 05-12 11:23:02.221 100-100/? D/Genymotion: Received Set

Some reference I have got are :

[Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked/37212750#37212750)

Please have a look and help me.