# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0001030c (code=1), thread 9561 (Thread-11153)

Tags: android, libgdx, fatal-error

I am working on LIBGDX game development. I am currently developing second level for the game . First level is working fine. I have used similar code for second level with changes in the design.But whenever I test for second level, I am getting this error. I have searched and changed a lot of code but I couldn't find the reason for this error. I have looked at all the stackoverflow links especially [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked) but it didn't help. I have been getting the below error

```
      r0 00010300  r1 3dce5e98  r2 513defa4  r3 00000026
      09-27 23:10:57.560 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     r4 00010300  r5 3dce5e98  r6                       00010300  r7 4e925e10
      09-27 23:10:57.560 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     r8 531b7c7c  r9 4e925e04  sl 4eb0e2c0  fp 531b7c94
        09-27 23:10:57.560 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     ip 51570144  sp 531b7c48   lr 5155e454  pc 5155f26c  cpsr 20000010
      09-27 23:10:57.560 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     d0  417606d3404e81c3  d1  417b428740623d72
     09-27 23:10:57.560 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     d2  4170000080000000  d3  bdcccccdbdcccccd
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #00  pc 0001a26c  /data/data/com.anusha.jungle.android/lib/libgdx-box2d.so (b2Fixture::CreateProxies(b2BroadPhase*, b2Transform const&)+8)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #01  pc 00019450  /data/data/com.anusha.jungle.android/lib/libgdx-box2d.so (b2Body::SetActive(bool)+80)
         09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #02  pc 0001f3b0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #03  pc 0004eb6f  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+394)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #04  pc 00000214  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache (deleted)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c08  57eaaf28  
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c0c  000c5c64  
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c10  409c2940  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c14  4219b0b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c18  00000000  
     09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c1c  409c25e8  /system/lib/libdvm.so
    09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c20  4219b0b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
      09-27 23:10:57.570 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c24  513dfc18  
     09-27 23:10:57.580 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c28  00000001  
    09-27 23:10:57.580 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c2c  409c2950  /system/lib/libdvm.so
     09-27 23:10:57.580 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c30  4219b0b8  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-heap (deleted)
     09-27 23:10:57.590 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c64  5155e454  /data/data/com.anusha.jungle.android/lib/libgdx-box2d.so (b2Body::SetActive(bool)+84)
        09-27 23:10:57.590 154-154/? I/DEBUG:     #01  531b7c68  4c4a7de0  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-LinearAlloc (deleted)
    09-27 23:10:57.590 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c6c  4eb0e2b0  
      09-27 23:10:57.590 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c70  00000000  
     09-27 23:10:57.590 154-154/? I/DEBUG:          531b7c74  4092f3b4          /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+116)
     /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
```

Comment: There might be something wrong with the `Body#setActive()` method (the way you call it). Give us some code to help you

Comment: hi @anusha check that your box2d bodies is destroying at correct place.