# How to play rtmp, rtsp, ts in android?

Tags: android, vitamio

How can i play rtmp,rtsp,ts link in android? I am using vitamio library but i got some error which i attached bellow. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

```
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 24828 (om.bdmaker.rtmp)

                                                    [ 05-30 13:28:30.710   395:  395 W/         ]
                                                    debuggerd: handling request: pid=24828 uid=10073 gid=10073 tid=24828
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: Did you use Vitamio-with-librtmp ?

Comment: https://github.com/mekya/Vitamio-with-librtmp

Comment: is there any full tutorial link you have?

Comment: Hi Are  you using BitMapFactory in your code ?

Comment: no. I just use the tutorial code

Comment: HI Read this.. might be useful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked