# (9644): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x65542220 in tid 9662 (Finalizer) How will the error be resolved?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, segmentation-fault

```
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): 
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): No native Android stacktrace (see debuggerd output).
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): 
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): 
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): =================================================================
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): used by your application.
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): =================================================================
03-01 11:10:29.602 E/mono-rt ( 9644): 
03-01 11:10:29.602 F/libc ( 9644): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x65542220 in tid 9662 (Finalizer)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked