# crash at HeapTaskDaemon

Tags: android, crash, garbage-collection

I get a crash when I open and close activity frequently. It looks like something wrong at GC, Does anyone know what happened?

```
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***   *** *** ***
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): Build fingerprint:   'Android/:7.1.2/:userdebug/dev-keys'
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): Revision: '0'
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): ABI: 'arm'
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): pid: 1059, tid: 1071, name: HeapTaskDaemon  >>> com.myapp <<<
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code -1729032960 (?), fault addr 0x4f468308
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     r0 993007c4  r1 b2468970  r2 00000002  r3 07ffffff
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     r4 00000001  r5 ffffffe1  r6 b0e805b0  r7 00000002
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     r8 00000000  r9 994b2dbc  sl a4f857c8  fp 00000014
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     ip 00000001  sp 9a75020c  lr b93007c0  pc b242e992  cpsr 000e0030
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): 
F/DEBUG   ( 7470): backtrace:
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #00 pc 00053992  /system/lib/libc.so (arena_run_reg_alloc+101)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #01 pc 00053fb9  /system/lib/libc.so (je_arena_malloc_hard+76)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #02 pc 0006131f  /system/lib/libc.so (je_malloc+122)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #03 pc 00048835  /system/lib/libc++.so (_Znwj+16)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #04 pc 0015496b  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9allocator8RosAlloc8BulkFreeEPNS_6ThreadEPPvj+958)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #05 pc 00177abb  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep10SweepArrayEPNS0_10accounting11AtomicStackINS_6mirror6ObjectEEEb+1086)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #06 pc 0017576f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep12ReclaimPhaseEv+166)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #07 pc 00175497  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector9MarkSweep9RunPhasesEv+306)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #08 pc 001701d5  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collector16GarbageCollector3RunENS0_7GcCauseEb+248)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #09 pc 00193621  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap22CollectGarbageInternalENS0_9collector6GcTypeENS0_7GcCauseEb+2368)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #10 pc 00198efd  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap12ConcurrentGCEPNS_6ThreadEb+68)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #11 pc 0019da57  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc4Heap16ConcurrentGCTask3RunEPNS_6ThreadE+18)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #12 pc 001b544f  /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc13TaskProcessor11RunAllTasksEPNS_6ThreadE+30)
F/DEBUG   ( 7470):     #13 pc 73a65627  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat (offset 0x279d000)
I/[Gralloc](  678):  ion device open success! fd = 50
```

Comment: Signal 11 Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked. And similar posts .

Comment: Are you releasing any resources in `onDestoy()` or in `onStop()`?

Comment: Any solutions for this? I am not releasing any resources on onDestroy or onStop.

Comment: Hi @hong, Did you found any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue. I checked with the link provided by ADM, there I am unable to get the exact method name where it is crashing.