# App crashing when map is loading and camera is moving to the current location

Tags: android, google-maps, debugging, android-camera

I'm currently debugging an app where it shows the map and it goes to the current location. When I look at the logs, it only shows this log

```
08-02 20:40:48.907 12558-12568/ph.com.appsample A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x5c in tid 12568 (FinalizerDaemon)
```

I tried removing the filtering of the logs and was able to retrieve this log

```
08-02 20:40:48.967 275-275/? I/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'samsung/j53gxx/j53g:5.1.1/LMY48B/J500HXXS1AQG1:'
Revision: '5'
ABI: 'arm'
pid: 12558, tid: 12568, name: FinalizerDaemon  >>> ph.com.appsample <<<
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x5c
08-02 20:40:48.997 275-275/? I/DEBUG:     r0 b7e1e8e0  r1 00000000  r2 
9b60f000  r3 00000000
    r4 b7e1e8e0  r5 0000005d  r6 136959c0  r7 ffffffff
    r8 712a9430  r9 b7a6fad0  sl 137295b0  fp 136959c0
    ip b6f80fa8  sp b45fca88  lr b6e86be1  pc 0000005c  cpsr 60070030
backtrace:
    #00 pc 0000005c  <unknown>
    #01 pc 0001fbdf  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6Parcel14freeDataNoInitEv+22)
    #02 pc 0001fc39  /system/lib/libbinder.so (_ZN7android6ParcelD1Ev+4)
    #03 pc 00083cbf  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
    #04 pc 00017f45  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
```

Is there anyway I can make this readable and does someone encounter this problem also?

Comment: these are not the complete log, check for the line which says `causedBy` it will have the reason for the app crashing

Comment: have you tried using any crashltytics report ? like a library to send report ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)