# How to resolve Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) code 1 in Android?

Tags: java, c++11, java-native-interface, android, opencv

I am developing an Android application using Opencv for image processing.

The processing part is called in java through JNI functions.

I am sending to c++ two Opencv `Mat` objects to find matching points.

The problem is that sometimes the app works and sometimes it doesn't even while using the same images.

I already check if the images aren't empty and that they are valid before sending them to the native part.

Here is the stack trace is get in Log

```
2019-04-26 12:52:06.980 24955-25666/com.grimg.coffretpfe A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 25666 (Thread-10)
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'samsung/zeroltexx/zerolte:7.0/NRD90M/G925FXXU6ERF5:user/release-keys'
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '10'
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'arm'
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: pid: 24955, tid: 25666, name: Thread-10  >>> com.grimg.coffretpfe <<<
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0
2019-04-26 12:52:07.078 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 b90a641c
2019-04-26 12:52:07.079 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     r4 ffffffff  r5 c09a4128  r6 b90a678c  r7 b90a6670
2019-04-26 12:52:07.079 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     r8 d33ee570  r9 97df7155  sl b90a6790  fp c06e3900
2019-04-26 12:52:07.079 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     ip c5ec4840  sp b90a6268  lr c5eb8043  pc c5eb8042  cpsr 600f0030
2019-04-26 12:52:07.081 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2019-04-26 12:52:07.081 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     #00 pc 00014042  /data/app/com.grimg.coffretpfe-2/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so (_Z6toGrayN2cv3MatES0_+1577)
2019-04-26 12:52:07.081 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     #01 pc 00014d65  /data/app/com.grimg.coffretpfe-2/lib/arm/libnative-lib.so (Java_com_grimg_coffretpfe_Activities_CompareActivity_detectFeatures+124)
2019-04-26 12:52:07.081 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     #02 pc 000adc99  /system/lib/libart.so (art_quick_generic_jni_trampoline+40)
2019-04-26 12:52:07.081 25766-25766/? A/DEBUG:     #03 pc 0000b0dd  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-jit-code-cache_24955_24955 (deleted)
```

I am running my app on a Samsung s6 edge, if this matters.

My native part contains two functions, `toGray` and here is the signature

```
double toGray(Mat captured, Mat target)
```

I didnt added the code because it's a lot of processing and operations

And the method I call in java is `detectFeatures`

```
extern "C" {
JNIEXPORT
jdouble
JNICALL Java_com_grimg_coffretpfe_Activities_CompareActivity_detectFeatures(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject instance,
    jlong addrRgba,
    jlong addrGray) {

 if (addrGray != NULL && addrRgba != NULL) {
    cv::Mat &mRgb = *(cv::Mat *) addrRgba;
    cv::Mat &mGray = *(cv::Mat *) addrGray;


    jdouble retVal;

    double conv = toGray(mRgb, mGray);

    retVal = (jdouble) conv;

    return retVal;
  }

   return -1;
 }
 }
```

I tried every available solution over here , but nothing works ,besides I don't really understand the problem so I don't know what to search for.

I hope you guys can help me solve this problem. Thanx in advance.

**EDIT**

```
double toGray(Mat captured, Mat target) {
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypointsCaptured;
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypointsTarget;

cv::Mat descriptorsCaptured;
cv::Mat descriptorsTarget;
//cv::Mat captured;
std::vector<cv::DMatch> matches;
std::vector<cv::DMatch> symMatches;

//std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches1;
//std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches2;
//Mat captured, target;
/*captured = imread("/storage/emulated/0/data/img1.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
target = imread("/storage/emulated/0/data/img3.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
if (!captured.data) {
    // Print error message and quit
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "I cant do this.");

}
if (!target.data) {
    // Print error message and quit
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "cant do nuthin.");


}*/
//cvtColor(capturedR, captured, CV_RGBA2GRAY);
//cvtColor(targetR, target, CV_RGBA2GRAY);


orb = ORB::create();

//Pre-process
resize(captured, captured, Size(480, 360));
medianBlur(captured, captured, 5);

resize(target, target, Size(480, 360));
medianBlur(target, target, 5);

orb->detectAndCompute(captured, noArray(), keypointsCaptured, descriptorsCaptured);
orb->detectAndCompute(target, noArray(), keypointsTarget, descriptorsTarget);
//__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "keypoints2 size = %d", keypointsTarget.size());
//__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "keypoints size = %d", keypointsCaptured.size());

//Match images based on k nearest neighbour
std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches1;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsCaptured, descriptorsTarget,
                 matches1, 2);
//__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "sometag", "Matches1 = %d",     matches1.size());
std::vector<std::vector<cv::DMatch> > matches2;
matcher.knnMatch(descriptorsTarget, descriptorsCaptured,
                 matches2, 2);
//Ratio filter
ratioTest(matches1);
ratioTest(matches2);
symmetryTest(matches1, matches2, symMatches);
ransacTest(symMatches,
           keypointsCaptured, keypointsTarget, matches);
const int symMatchCount = matches.size();

Point2f point1;
Point2f point2;
float median;
float meanBoy = 0;
float greatest = 0;
float lowest = 0;
int count = 0;
vector<float> angleList;
vector<Point2f> point1List;
vector<Point2f> point2List;

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    point1 = keypointsCaptured[matches[i].queryIdx].pt;
    point2 = keypointsTarget[matches[i].trainIdx].pt;
    point1List.push_back(point1);
    point2List.push_back(point2);

    deltaY = ((360 - point2.y) - (360 - point1.y));
    deltaX = (point2.x + 480 - point1.x);

    angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI;
    cout << "ORB Matching Results" << angle << endl;
    //if (angle > greatest) greatest = angle;
    //if (angle < lowest) lowest = angle;
    meanBoy += angle;

    angleList.push_back(angle);
    //std::cout << "points " << "(" << point1.x << "," <<360-point1.y<<") (" << point2.x << ","<<360-point2.y<<") angle:" <<angle << std::endl;
    //std::cout << angle << std::endl;

}
// do something with the best points...

//std::cout << "Mean" << meanBoy/symMatchCount << std::endl;
vector<float> angleLCopy(angleList);
std::sort(angleLCopy.begin(), angleLCopy.end());
/*               if(angleList.size() % 2 == 0)
                         median = (angleList[angleList.size()/2 - 1] + angleList[angleList.size()/2]) / 2;
                 else
                         median = angleList[angleList.size()/2];
                */
size_t medianIndex = angleLCopy.size() / 2;
nth_element(angleLCopy.begin(), angleLCopy.begin() + medianIndex, angleLCopy.end());
median = angleLCopy[medianIndex];
std::cout << "new Median method " << angleLCopy[medianIndex] << std::endl;
//std::cout << "greatest " << greatest << "|| lowest "<< lowest << std::endl;

//std::cout << "No of matches by shehel: " << angleList[35] << " size " << symMatchCount << std::endl;
//std::cout << "Median" << median << std::endl;
//std::cout << matches.size()<< std::endl;
count = 0;
for (auto i = matches.begin(); i != matches.end();) {

    //std::cout << angleList.at(count)<< std::endl;

    //if (angle > greatest) greatest = angle;
    //if (angle < lowest) lowest = angle;
    point1 = point1List.at(count);
    point2 = point2List.at(count);

    deltaY = ((360 - point2.y) - (360 - point1.y));
    deltaX = ((point2.x + 480) - point1.x);

    angle = atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / PI;
    //angleList.push_back (angle);
    cout << "Is it sorted? " << angleList.at(count) << endl;

    if (angleList.at(count) > (median + 5) | angleList.at(count) < (median - 5)) {
        //cout << "bitch is gone" << angleList.at(count) << endl;
        matches.erase(i);
        count++;

    }
        //{i++; count++;}
    else {
        cout << "Points A (" << point1.x << ", " << point1.y << ") B (" <<
             point2.x + 480 << ", " << point2.y << ") Deltas of X" << deltaX << " Y " <<
             deltaY << "  Angle " << angle << endl;
        cout << "aint going no where" << angleList.at(count) << endl;

        ++i;
        count++;
        //if (angle>0.5 | angle < -0.7)
        //matches.erase(matches.begin()+i);
        // do something with the best points...
    }
}

return (static_cast<double>(matches.size()) / static_cast<double>(matches1.size()));
}
```

Comment: Well, what is the line of code at address 0x00014042? Use addr2line to find out (e.g. `arm-linux-androideabi-addr2line -Cfe libnative-lib.so 00014042`, where `libnative-lib.so` is the _unstripped_ version of the library).

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you . Should I run this command in terminal ?

Comment: Have you tried this??https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked  and another thing,  I don"t think there is any issue with the output of toGray(), but just to be sure can you check by not calling toGray() function

Comment: Yeah I checked whithout toGray and it's working . Even if I try to pass the same image in the function it works always

Comment: I'm trying to use ndk-stack but I can't find the the object directory obj, can you tell me how to find it ?

Comment: @Michael I executed the command and I've got this in terminal `toGray(cv::Mat, cv::Mat)
??:?`

Comment: Even ndk-stack gave me the same result

Comment: Looks to me like you passed the stripped version of the library to addr2line.

Comment: @Michael I got working, I edited the question and added the toGray code, and terminal tells me that the line of the error is 283, which is in my code this line ` median = angleLCopy[medianIndex];`

Comment: Ok, then it seems to me like the most likely reason is that `angleLCopy` is empty. The `vector` operator `[]` doesn't perform any bounds checks, so trying to access the first element of an empty vector using `[]` results in undefined behavior (e.g. a segmentation fault).

Comment: I commented that chunk of code and it's like working for now. Thank you for your quick response :)

Comment: But my results aren't correct anymore

Comment: I used the debugger for a working scenario, I noticed that matches array is full of values, and for a not working one, matches' size is 0, that's why the crash.