# React native 0.59 application crashes with libc error

Tags: c++, react-native, crash, libc

I'm having the following problem on react-native@0.59.9. It happens randomly on some screens in the app. any idea what would cause this? should I open a bug report in the react-native repo?
Here is the log from the logcat:

```
06-16 20:00:50.570   624  1011 E libnav  : 
CablComputeBacklightLevel(): UpdateType = DifferentSceneUpdate
06-16 20:00:51.629 15016 15070 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x13c in tid 15070 (mqt_js)
06-16 20:00:51.707  2090  2090 E wpa_supp: RSSI=-41;LINKSPEED=72;NOISE=9999;FREQUENCY=2437;
06-16 20:00:51.708  1704  2009 E WifiConfigManager: updateConfiguration freq=2437 BSSID=44:d9:**:**:24:31 RSSI=-41 "MyAppName"WPA_PSK
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'HUAWEI/TRT-L21A/HWTRT-Q:7.0/HUAWEITRT-L21A/C185B178:user/release-keys'
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : pid: 15016, tid: 15070, name: mqt_js  >>> my.package.name <<<
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x13c
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     r0 00000134  r1 81b43720  r2 7c3db4e0  r3 00000001
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     r4 84a06744  r5 851a6bd3  r6 84a00210  r7 8607db98
06-16 20:00:51.753 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     r8 fffffffb  r9 58839230  sl 815e6cc0  fp 598afb80
06-16 20:00:51.754 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     ip 00000000  sp 8607daa0  lr 84dff6d5  pc 8528c68a  cpsr 80070030
06-16 20:00:51.754 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :
06-16 20:00:51.754 15535 15535 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
06-16 20:00:51.755 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 0000368a  <anonymous:85289000>
06-16 20:00:51.755 15535 15535 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0004c6d3  <anonymous:84db3000>
06-16 20:00:52.187   676   676 E         : [E/capacity_limit_control] not demo version, not set power control prop!
06-16 20:00:53.602 15535 15535 E         : debuggerd: failed to kill process 15016: No such process
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crash on `CablComputeBacklightLevel()` looks like a bug in the application code. You need the stack trace to figure out where it's happening and investigate further.

Here are some suggestions that could help:
[Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)

After that it's mostly debugging.