# Try impl C library on Android but app crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, decode

I want to add C library to my project. [lzfse](https://github.com/lzfse/lzfse) for decode img via apple algorithm.

I have added c files to project

added CmakeLines file:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/lzfse/CMakeLists.txt"
        version "3.10.2"
    }
}
```

I have written JNI for `decode`:

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_com_android_Decompressor_decode(

        JNIEnv* env, jclass cls, jobject src, jobject dst

) {

    uint8_t* src_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,src);
    const size_t src_size = (const size_t) (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, src);

    uint8_t* dst_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env,dst);

    size_t dst_size = (size_t) (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, dst);

    jlong test = lzfse_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);

    return (jint) test;
}
```

then I call from kt decode fun:

```
 val buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)

            val buf_out = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(byteArray.size *20)
            val size= decode(dstArray = buf_out, srcArray = buf)
```

But
My app just crashes

> 2020-02-25 20:12:25.717 28603-28603/com.android A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 in tid 28603 (), pid 28603 ()

Where did I lose?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked

Comment: @Nick the question is about where I wrong when adding the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the crash! After some time I have decided to publish the working code.
So, the call native c++ from project:

```
  private val dstArray: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(DESTINATION_BUFFER_CAPACITY)
  private val srcArray: ByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(SRC_BUFFER_CAPACITY)

 decode(srcArray.put(byteArray), dstArray)
```

Here instead of:

```
 val buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)
 val size= decode(dstArray = buf_out, srcArray = buf)
```

I allocate a direct buffer  via  `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect` and put the source array in buffer  `srcArray.put(byteArray)`.
Because as [@Botje](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1548468/botje) said in his [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403191/6352712) :

> Wrapping a ByteArray does not result in a direct buffer (at least on
>   Android).

my JNI:

```
JNIEXPORT  JNICALL
Java_com_android_Decompressor_decode(

       JNIEnv *env, jclass cls, jobject src, jobject dst

) {

     uint8_t *src_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, src);
const size_t src_size = (const size_t) (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, src);
uint8_t *dst_buffer = (*env)->GetDirectBufferAddress(env, dst);
size_t dst_size = (size_t) (*env)->GetDirectBufferCapacity(env, dst);
lzfse_decode_buffer(dst_buffer, dst_size, src_buffer, src_size, NULL);

}
```

So I almost haven't changed JNI.
But in my first code sample, I have found that all works until the line:

```
  //...
  return (jint) test;
```

The line caused the crash.

In my case, I didn't need return value so I rewrite JNI function without return any values, but I think it possible to find where I have failed with the return value.
Thanks, guys who tried to give some help, I hope my post also can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping a `ByteArray` [does not result in a direct buffer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/9877ade9617bb0db6e59aa2a54719a9bc92600f3/luni/src/main/java/java/nio/ByteArrayBuffer.java#238) (at least on Android).
You will need to call `GetByteArrayElements` to get a (possibly copied) pointer.

Comment: thank you @Botje for your help. As you said `Wrapping a ByteArray does not result in a direct buffer `. So I allocated a direct buffer for my source.