# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) , fault addr 0x0 in tid 22274 (hwuiTask1)

Tags: android, android-service, surfaceview, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

App is getting crash when I am using exoplayer for video and getting this error "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR) , fault addr 0x0 in tid 22274 (hwuiTask1)" .When I am using `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"`then its working only , but in my case false is creating issue to display content . So what i did , I implemented layertype as software for video view only but its not displaying video . I checked many solutions like [Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)  but still not resolved issue , can anyone help me to resolve this issue. Here is my stack trace
`signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x0 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG: Cause: null pointer dereference 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x0  00000073d1a1f448  x1  0000007433421820  x2  0000000000000020  x3  0000000000000002 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x4  00000073d03c65a0  x5  00000073d03c65c0  x6  000000743708e940  x7  000000743708e760 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x8  00000073d1a1f3c0  x9  0000000000000088  x10 000000000000000f  x11 00000073c0000000 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x12 0000000000000020  x13 0000000000011bb8  x14 0000000000000001  x15 0000000000000000 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x16 00000074c54ee890  x17 00000074c6a6b640  x18 00000073b76de000  x19 0000000000000000 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x20 0000007433421820  x21 00000073d1a1f448  x22 00000074c54e9b28  x23 0000007432b9c020 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x24 00000074c54e9b78  x25 0000000000000000  x26 0000000000000001  x27 0000000000000003 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     x28 0000000000000000  x29 0000007432b99e20 2021-09-02 18:45:35.646 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:     sp  0000007432b99e00  lr  00000074c54b10c0  pc  00000074c6a6b65c 2021-09-02 18:45:35.932 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG: backtrace: 2021-09-02 18:45:35.932 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 000000000000f65c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+28) (BuildId: e694ec4393425b1d99ea7621766c5862) 2021-09-02 18:45:35.932 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 00000000000a70bc  /system/lib64/libgui.so (android::Vector<android::ComposerState>::do_destroy(void*, unsigned long) const+32) (BuildId: 7a4120ceec9f946dbd431c5623be1c15) 2021-09-02 18:45:35.933 22280-22280/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 000000000001610c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::VectorImpl::finish_vector()+80) (BuildId: e694ec4393425b1d99ea7621766c5862)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue , might be it will help others. Issue was with exoplayer when i used surface view to play video with `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` for some devices like moto e(7) plus , One Plus 6 . So , I added `app:surface_type="texture_view"` in exoplayer layout file like this

```
<com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
     android:id="@+id/video_player"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_margin="0dp"
     android:background="@color/black"
     android:padding="0dp"
     app:surface_type="texture_view"
     app:resize_mode="fixed_height">

</com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView>
```