# Jetpack Compose app randomly crashes when orientation change

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My Jetpack Compose app randomly crashes on screen orientation change. It does not happen every time. But if keep rotating, it will eventually crash.

By inspecting the log, I have no clue which part of my codes are relevant so I don't know what to post.

Here is the error log that I think might be relevant. Any guide to help narrow down the issue is appreciated.

```
2023-10-05 18:09:08.098 27097-27097 libc                    A  Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 27097 (my_app), pid 27097 (my_app)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.100  1213-3746  InputDispatcher         I  setInputWindows displayId=0 RotationLayer#0 Window{a84c123 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{ff5f65f u0 StatusBar} recents_animation_input_consumer Window{615ae9b u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper} 
2023-10-05 18:09:08.102   574-574   hwcomposer              I  [HWCLayer] setHwlayerType(), id:1354, release queue sp, type 3 -> 2  
2023-10-05 18:09:08.102   574-574   hwcomposer              I  [DBQ] (q2:0xb4000079a15c9b30) Buffer queue is destroyed, m_id(1354)  
2023-10-05 18:09:08.102   574-574   hwcomposer              I  [DBQ] (q2:0xb4000079a15c9b30) ~DisplayBufferQueue(), m_id(1354), release buf  
2023-10-05 18:09:08.102   574-574   hwcomposer              I  [DBQ] (q2:0xb4000079a15c9b30) Free Slot(0), handle=0xb4000079415d1370, 4608000 -> 0  
2023-10-05 18:09:08.107   880-880   thermal_repeater        I  [recvMdThermalInfo] ret=33, strLen=127,  2, 32767, -127, 111, 32767, 3996
2023-10-05 18:09:08.112  5763-5813  SP                      I  Registering hmmdictionary.2023022208, url: https://www.gstatic.com/android/keyboard/hmmpack/2023060504/metadata_2023060504.json, constraints: m:*:*:*, flags: bg, requested: 2023022208, current: 2023022208
2023-10-05 18:09:08.116  1213-1688  InputDispatcher         I  setInputWindows displayId=0 RotationLayer#0 Window{a84c123 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{ff5f65f u0 StatusBar} recents_animation_input_consumer Window{615ae9b u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper} 
2023-10-05 18:09:08.118  5763-5813  SP                      I  Syncing content_cache (2023050217) with slices: [bb54f3d41c84c1073a121e9c77bad4fe, 8722425f4121ffdea802b1066df73991, fa1da98da1212aad6fb9a8efaff48148], metadata: true
2023-10-05 18:09:08.133  1213-1688  InputDispatcher         I  setInputWindows displayId=0 RotationLayer#0 Window{a84c123 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{ff5f65f u0 StatusBar} recents_animation_input_consumer Window{615ae9b u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper} 
2023-10-05 18:09:08.134  5763-5763  PhoneWindow             V  DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 8, Parent = android.view.ViewRootImpl@71e0b06, this = DecorView@bcab5c7[InputMethod]
2023-10-05 18:09:08.150  1213-1688  InputDispatcher         I  setInputWindows displayId=0 RotationLayer#0 Window{a84c123 u0 NavigationBar0} Window{ff5f65f u0 StatusBar} recents_animation_input_consumer Window{615ae9b u0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper} 
2023-10-05 18:09:08.168   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63006, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.206 27180-27180 crash_dump64            I  obtaining output fd from tombstoned, type: kDebuggerdTombstone
2023-10-05 18:09:08.206   551-551   tombstoned              I  received crash request for pid 27097
2023-10-05 18:09:08.210 27180-27180 crash_dump64            I  performing dump of process 27097 (target tid = 27097)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.227 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2023-10-05 18:09:08.227 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  Build fingerprint: 'Ulefone/Note_9P/Note_9P:11/RP1A.200720.011/1656643796:user/release-keys'
2023-10-05 18:09:08.228 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  Revision: '0'
2023-10-05 18:09:08.228 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  ABI: 'arm64'
2023-10-05 18:09:08.228 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  Timestamp: 2023-10-05 18:09:08+0800
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  pid: 27097, tid: 27097, name: my_app  >>> com.example.my_app <<<
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  uid: 10370
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  Cause: null pointer dereference
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x0  0000000000000000  x1  b4000077b4af6b6d  x2  fffffffffffffffd  x3  626173652e61706b
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x4  6b70612e65736162  x5  626173652e61706b  x6  6b70612e65736162  x7  b4000077b4ae4590
2023-10-05 18:09:08.229 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x8  b4000077b4af7d38  x9  0000000000000051  x10 b4000077b4aea830  x11 b4000077b4af6b30
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x12 0000007ffdae7370  x13 b4000077b4ae4f50  x14 b400007854aecc00  x15 0000000000000000
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x16 00000079f713a5c0  x17 00000079f85d8200  x18 00000079fabdc000  x19 0000000000000000
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x20 b400007784b3ad90  x21 0000000000000011  x22 000000000000000d  x23 b4000077e4b266c0
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x24 000000000000000d  x25 b4000077b4af7d30  x26 000000000000004d  x27 0000000000000028
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      x28 b4000077b4aea7d9  x29 0000007ffdae7490
2023-10-05 18:09:08.230 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A      lr  00000079f710e2a8  sp  0000007ffdae7310  pc  00000079f710e2bc  pst 0000000060000000
2023-10-05 18:09:08.244  5763-5813  SP                      I  Sync for emoticon_content_description succeeded in 230 ms: no changes
2023-10-05 18:09:08.244  5763-5813  SP                      I  GC for 'emoticon_content_description' (10) with ttl of 0 ms took 0 ms (0/0/0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.274  1213-1343  WifiVendorHal           E  getWifiLinkLayerStats_1_3_Internal(l.973) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }
2023-10-05 18:09:08.283   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63007, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.306  5763-5813  Dictionary...ngStrategy I  DictionarySlicingStrategy.getSlices():78 getSlices(): hmmdictionary.2023022208
2023-10-05 18:09:08.307  5763-5813  Dictionary...ngStrategy I  DictionarySlicingStrategy.getSlices():108 getSlices(): result {slices=[hmmdictionary:zh_HK_2023022208], last batch=true, sync metadata=false}
2023-10-05 18:09:08.307  5763-5813  SP                      I  Syncing hmmdictionary (2023022208) with slices: [zh_HK_2023022208], metadata: false
2023-10-05 18:09:08.312  5763-5813  SP                      I  Sync for content_cache succeeded in 200 ms: no changes
2023-10-05 18:09:08.362  5763-5813  SP                      I  GC for 'content_cache' (10) with ttl of 0 ms took 0 ms (0/0/0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.377  5763-5813  SP                      I  Sync for hmmdictionary succeeded in 72 ms: no changes
2023-10-05 18:09:08.377  5763-5813  SP                      I  GC for 'hmmdictionary' (10) with ttl of 0 ms took 0 ms (0/0/0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.378  5763-27174 SuperpacksManagerBase   I  SuperpacksManagerBase$2.onSyncSuccess():189 sync(): complete {old=[zh_HK_2023022208], new=[zh_HK_2023022208], metadata=false, last batch=true}
2023-10-05 18:09:08.380  5763-27171 HmmDataFacilitator      I  HmmDataFacilitator.setDownloadedPacks():324 Opening pack for language zh_HK
2023-10-05 18:09:08.399   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63008, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.515   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63009, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
---------------------------- PROCESS STARTED (27182) for package com.example.my_app ----------------------------
2023-10-05 18:09:08.630   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63010, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.743 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A  backtrace:
2023-10-05 18:09:08.743 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #00 pc 000000000003f2bc  /system/lib64/libandroidfw.so (android::Theme::SetTo(android::Theme const&)+2092) (BuildId: 53102fdd0971ff2168de15b5dbfc47ff)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.743 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #01 pc 000000000011ee44  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeThemeCopy(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, long, long, long, long)+132) (BuildId: d8680db49c32cc8d244699769942d8f5)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #02 pc 00000000001fda50  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (art_jni_trampoline+176) (BuildId: 8fa99c57ca3ed1e573c90605a6326b464427a0c1)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #03 pc 00000000001337e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_static_stub+568) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #04 pc 00000000001a9804  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+228) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #05 pc 000000000031c050  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToCompiledCodeBridge(art::Thread*, art::ArtMethod*, art::ShadowFrame*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+376) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #06 pc 0000000000313298  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, false>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+696) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #07 pc 000000000068ccb4  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStaticRange+412) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #08 pc 000000000012dc94  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static_range+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #09 pc 000000000037678c  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.AssetManager.setThemeTo+28)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #10 pc 000000000068a634  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualRange+1124) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #11 pc 000000000012db14  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual_range+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #12 pc 000000000037d574  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.ResourcesImpl$ThemeImpl.setTo+28)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #13 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #14 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #15 pc 000000000037cfec  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.content.res.Resources$Theme.setTo+8)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #16 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.744 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #17 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #18 pc 00000000001fedd2  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x124f000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.initializeTheme+62)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #19 pc 0000000000689438  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #20 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #21 pc 00000000001fee38  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x124f000) (android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.setTheme+12)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #22 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #23 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #24 pc 000000000047708a  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x124f000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateDecor+58)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #25 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #26 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.745 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #27 pc 0000000000477b46  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x124f000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.installDecor+18)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #28 pc 0000000000689438  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeDirect+1248) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #29 pc 000000000012d914  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_direct+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #30 pc 0000000000475878  /system/framework/framework.jar (offset 0x124f000) (com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.getDecorView+16)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #31 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #32 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #33 pc 0000000000194ca8  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~CHv-cnisWEjeEIW5QJqMkw==/com.example.my_app-Ep2GoAjSLqVcZIKAXnvlGA==/base.apk] (androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt.setContent+28)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #34 pc 0000000000689d10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #35 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #36 pc 0000000000194c72  [anon:dalvik-classes.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~CHv-cnisWEjeEIW5QJqMkw==/com.example.my_app-Ep2GoAjSLqVcZIKAXnvlGA==/base.apk] (androidx.activity.compose.ComponentActivityKt.setContent$default+10)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #37 pc 0000000000689d10  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+1224) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #38 pc 000000000012d994  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_static+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #39 pc 0000000000006190  [anon:dalvik-classes5.dex extracted in memory from /data/app/~~CHv-cnisWEjeEIW5QJqMkw==/com.example.my_app-Ep2GoAjSLqVcZIKAXnvlGA==/base.apk!classes5.dex] (com.example.my_app.MainActivity.onCreate+28)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #40 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #41 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #42 pc 00000000001a9914  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.performCreate+88)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #43 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #44 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #45 pc 00000000001a98a2  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Activity.performCreate+2)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #46 pc 0000000000686db0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtual+1520) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #47 pc 000000000012d814  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (mterp_op_invoke_virtual+20) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #48 pc 0000000000213d06  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate+6)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #49 pc 00000000003094e0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.8567976207078191854)+264) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.746 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #50 pc 0000000000311850  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #51 pc 0000000000312bac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #52 pc 0000000000175678  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+46400) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #53 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #54 pc 0000000000197218  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747   594-594   SurfaceFlinger          I  operator()(), mtkRenderCntDebug 63011, screenshot (BackColorSurface#0)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #55 pc 00000000003095e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.8567976207078191854)+528) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #56 pc 0000000000311850  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #57 pc 0000000000312bac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #58 pc 0000000000175678  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+46400) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #59 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #60 pc 00000000001970d8  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #61 pc 00000000003095e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.8567976207078191854)+528) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #62 pc 0000000000311850  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #63 pc 0000000000312bac  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<false, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1772) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #64 pc 0000000000175678  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+46400) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #65 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #66 pc 000000000019f868  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #67 pc 00000000003095e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.8567976207078191854)+528) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #68 pc 0000000000311850  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #69 pc 0000000000313b6c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (bool art::interpreter::DoCall<true, true>(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, art::ShadowFrame&, art::Instruction const*, unsigned short, art::JValue*)+1692) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.747 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #70 pc 00000000001755f8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::interpreter::ExecuteSwitchImplCpp<true, false>(art::interpreter::SwitchImplContext*)+46272) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.748 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #71 pc 000000000013f7d8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteSwitchImplAsm+8) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.748 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #72 pc 000000000019f4f4  /system/framework/framework.jar (android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.748 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #73 pc 00000000003095e8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::Execute(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame&, art::JValue, bool, bool) (.llvm.8567976207078191854)+528) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
2023-10-05 18:09:08.748 27180-27180 DEBUG                   A        #74 pc 0000000000311850  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::interpreter::ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridge(art::Thread*, art::CodeItemDataAccessor const&, art::ShadowFrame*, art::JValue*)+200) (BuildId: 1ad871ae595961595bfa64be35e125bc)
```

Comment: Jetpack compose... a weird detour in Android Developing.

Comment: could you provide some code of the screen that you are experiencing the crash?

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't have problem inside your code it from the operating system as first line in the logs mentioned.

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x8 in tid 27097 (my_app), pid 27097 (my_app)

You can check this stackoverflow post for your reference: [Android Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x636f7d89 (code=1). How can it be tracked down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17840521/android-fatal-signal-11-sigsegv-at-0x636f7d89-code-1-how-can-it-be-tracked)